# Downsides of using \par instead of two new lines

Tags: best-practices, paragraphs

Coming from an HTML background using `<p>` to mark paragraphs I consequently use `\par` to mark paragraphs instead of using two consecutive blank lines. This feels more semantic (of course I realize this argument is bogus) and after a few years of LaTeX this habit is hard to lose. It also feels handier in (for instance) enumeration environments, the line with `\item` doesn't get its own `\par` while the other paragraphs do, using whitespace between consecutive `\item`'s, but as said before, this is just a feeling.

I was wondering whether there are other people doing this or if there are any reasons to *not* do it this way? The only argument I can come up with could be readability (more whitespace is easier for the eyes) but if there are others I might have to get rid of this tic.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your co-authors will be very surprised when they see your source code, and very likely the first thing they will do is to replace each `\par` with a blank line.

There are some situations (like macros, lists, and situations such as `{\centering Foo\par}` or `{\small Foo\par}`) in which `\par` might be a good idea, but most of the time it is both hard-to-read and non-standard.

Comment: Just to elaborate on this answer - using \par is very hard to read because it is visually difficult to identify paragraph breaks. Blank lines are much more natural to the human reader of the source.

Comment: When using a highlighting editor that difficulty is greatly diminished though. But I conclude my habit is uncommon and unnecessary, it's time to throw it away :).

Comment: There is one place `\par` can work well: when you are trying to visually keep blocks of text together in your input file.  In these cases putting the `\par` on a line by itself, with some whitespace before it, retains the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 7):

Runaway macros: if you have something like

```
I have something to say\footnote{Although I forget to end this footnote
\par
Oh, and another thing.
```

then the complaint about the runaway argument will take much longer to be generated.  All macros are, in effect `\long`.

Comment: This doesn't look right. `\par` tokens are `\par` tokens.