# When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, best-practices, syntax

What is the difference between `\par`, `\newline`, `\\` and blank lines?
When should I use which one?

Comment: Well, use `\par` when you want a new paragraph (and don't wan to insert a blank line for some reason, such as in macro/environment definitions), and use `\\ ` in `array` and `tabular`.  That's the rules I have been following.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for the comment, what about `\newline` then?

Comment: @zyy: Hmm. I think that would make a good question as I don't use `\newline` much. I think the only place I use that is within the `todonotes` package macros (which are not part of the final document).

Comment: you may want to read `TeX by topic`, Sec. 2.9,

Comment: See also [David's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650518/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-or-newline#comment1621329_650518) on this -- if I understood correctly, `⟨blank line⟩\noindent` mostly (except when `\parskip` is nonzero) works the same as `\\`, but `\\` is better **semantically** in case a new paragraph is not "intended".

Answer (score 236, accepted):

`\par` is a TeX primitive and is the same as a blank line (except in special environments such as `verbatim` where the usual rules don't apply). It ends horizontal mode, causes TeX to break the horizontal text into lines placed on the current vertical list, and exercises the page breaker which may possibly cause the next page to be shipped out.

`\\` is different in almost every respect. It is a macro not a primitive, and its definition changes wildly in almost every LaTeX definition. The definition in normal text, a `center` environment, a `flushleft` environment and a table are all different.

In normal running text when it forces a linebreak it is essentially a shorthand for `\newline`. This does *not* end horizontal mode or end the paragraph. It just inserts some glue and penalties at that point into the horizontal material, so that when the paragraph does end, a line-break will occur at that point, with the short line padded with white space.

`\\` at the end of a paragraph causes bad output with an empty, maximally under-full, box, and so you get a warning about badness 10000, the visual effect looks a bit like extra vertical space but it is not: it is an extra spurious line at the end of the paragraph, and for example it is not dropped at a page break and will break widow/club line calculations.

You should rarely need to use `\\` in documents apart from its use in alignments (where it  is a macro based on the `\cr` primitive), and you should rarely need `\par` in documents as a blank line should suffice.

Comment: a consequence of using `\\ `instead of paragraph breaks is that (la)tex continues to load text into memory, and doesn't actually output anything until an actual paragraph break occurs.  this may not be so important now, with memory capacity being so large, but when memory was a much more scarce resource, failing to use paragraph breaks was a sure way to run out of memory and crash the job before it finished.  it will still slow down the processing when the "paragraphs" are very long.

Comment: @JonasStein hmm I would have said better to ask a new question but someone did that but it was closed as duplicate of this (not by me:-) so OK if you edit the question to ask about blank lines I'll add something here (basically they are the same as `\par` except in verbatim and other special cases)

Comment: I've seen people say that using `\\ ` is a cause of bad box warnings. Is it? cc. @barbarabeeton

Comment: @cfr `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph causes spectacularly bad output with an empty, maximally underfull, box, and so you get a warning about badness 10000, if that is what you mean. I wouldn't say that `\\ ` itself makes the warning, as that makes it sound like it is some kind of spurious warning and the warning itself is the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But I can't get it to give me any warnings at all. Or did you mean it only does so at the end of paragraphs?

Comment: `\\ ` mid paragraph usually doesn't generate anything that will generate a warning it is `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph forcing a line break after the last text in the paragraph so forcing the following line to be empty

Comment: I've been using `EnterKey+\ \\ ` to skip a line while having the following text not indented, I never knew why it worked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just leaving a blank line in the source code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What I meant is that `<text> <empty line> \ \\<text>` produces a visual similar (if not the same) as `\bigskip \noindent`. No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Okay, the white space has different height in each case, but they look otherwise the same.

Comment: @Jim no `\ \\ ` is completely wrong as I tried to explain in this answer. It doesn't add vertical space it is exactly like `ignore-this\\ ` it adds a spurious line to the paragraph. Unlike vertical space the blank line of text doesn't stretch or shrink, isn't dropped at the top of a page if a page break happens there, and it messes up all latex's control over page breaking after the first line of a paragraph as the counting of lines will be out by one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you please explain why we should rarely need \par in documents in detail?

Comment: @Jie why would you use `\par`? It is so much more natural to use blank lines between blocks of text to denote paragraph breaks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your reply. Because blank lines have same effects (to start a new paragraph) no matter how many blank lines there are. So it seems that \par is more obvious than nothing (blank lines) for me.

Comment: @Jie if you are writing text then writing it all on on line with `\par`  is just very weird compared to breaking paragraphs with a blank line (as done in many other systems, eg this web site). I have been looking at latex documents for over 30 years and I don't think I have ever seen a document that does that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I will improve my habits.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I think one of the principles of coding is to be explicit, while blank lines are not explicit (to the compiler), what if the definition of blank lines changes?

Comment: @zyy I can not understand your comment. Blank lines are reported as `\par` so if you go `\def\par{hello}`, then whether you use `\par` or a blank line in the document it is an explicit instruction to typeset "hello".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess what I wanted to say is, a blank line may not be explicit to some people: for me, at least, a explicit command looks safer.

Comment: @zyy it is best to dispel any miscomprehension that blank lines can be used for cosmetic "pretty print" fomatting of the source file, as they can in some languages. It is an explicit instruction to end a paragraph. Of the hundreds of thousands of example documents posted here for example, I do not see any where text is all on one line separated by `\par`, almost everyone uses the intended, natural, markup for end of paragraph, which is a blank line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the clarification, I think I should get myself used to it...

Answer (score 58):

In text mode, `\par` starts a new paragraph, while `\\` ends the current line.

So when to use each one?

`\\` should be used with parsimony, when you want to break of the rhythm of your current argumentation, but without jumping to a new idea / argument (which would require starting a new paragraph).

`\par` should actually be used even less frequently. Not that you do not want to start new paragraphs (you do want to keep paragraphs to reasonable lengths!), but you should start new paragraphs by leaving an empty line in your TeX code. This has the exact same effect as using `\par`, but will make your code much more readable. `\par` is therefore mostly used when defining macros.

---

Note that outside of text mode, `\par` will usually lead to an error, while `\\` usually works as expected to start a new line (like while in an `tabular` or `array`).

Comment: `\\`  in text usually works except when it says `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end`.  (e.g., dual `\\` to produce two blank lines in a paragraph ... there are more reliable ways to do that.)   [gosh — don't understand where that

Comment: the previous one by me showed my non-understanding of markdown (or whatever it is).  i was trying to use backslashes, and the output was all to pot ... and in the allowed 5 minutes i couldn't sort the problem.  must remember to keep my mouth shut in future... :-(

Comment: @wasteofspace to put a double backslash in code markdown you need to type backtick, dobule backslash, space, backtick. This yields `\\ `. I guess you comment above was meant to be «`\\ ` in text usually works except when it says `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end`. (e.g., dual `\\ ` to produce two blank lines in a paragraph ... there are more reliable ways to do that.)», right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so your suggestion is to use blank lines as much as possible, and `\\` and `\par` should only be used in environments or macro definition, is that right? What about `\newline` then?

Comment: Also I think one of the principles of coding is to be explicit, while blank lines are not explicit (to the compiler), what if the definition of blank lines change?

Comment: If the definition of blank lines change then won't every single .tex file in existence crash?

Comment: @zyy a blank line is reported as `\par`  so if you change the definiton of `\par` you change the definition of blank lines. There is no sense in which `\par` is more explicit. Blank line is the standard markup for end of paragraph in latex, the fact that `\par`also works is an implementation detail.