# Package clash between amsthm and lineno

Tags: packages

I found a clash between packages amsthm and lineno. Below is some sample code. Does anyone know what I should do to avoid this ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\title{It's hard schnock's life}
\author{Anne Onymous}

\maketitle

\noindent C'est un trou de verdure où chante une rivière,\\
Accrochant follement aux herbes des haillons\\
D'argent ; où le soleil, de la montagne fière,\\
Luit : c'est un petit val qui mousse de rayons.\\
\\
Un soldat jeune, bouche ouverte, tête nue,\\
Et la nuque baignant dans le frais cresson bleu,\\
Dort ; il est étendu dans l'herbe, sous la nue,\\
Pâle dans son lit vert où la lumière pleut.\\
\\
\\Les pieds dans les glaïeuls, il dort. Souriant comme
\\Sourirait un enfant malade, il fait un somme :
\\Nature, berce-le chaudement : il a froid.
\\
\\Les parfums ne font pas frissonner sa narine ;
\\Il dort dans le soleil, la main sur sa poitrine,
\\Tranquille. Il a deux trous rouges au côté droit.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading `lineno` *after* `amsthm` solves the problem. Often, package clashes are resolved by changing the order in which you load the packages in question.

Note that the way you use `\\` is considered bad practice. For more detail, [see this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\title{It's hard schnock's life}
\author{Anne Onymous}

\maketitle

\noindent C'est un trou de verdure où chante une rivière,\\
Accrochant follement aux herbes des haillons\\
D'argent ; où le soleil, de la montagne fière,\\
Luit : c'est un petit val qui mousse de rayons.\\

Un soldat jeune, bouche ouverte, tête nue,\\
Et la nuque baignant dans le frais cresson bleu,\\
Dort ; il est étendu dans l'herbe, sous la nue,\\
Pâle dans son lit vert où la lumière pleut.\\

Les pieds dans les glaïeuls, il dort. Souriant comme
\\Sourirait un enfant malade, il fait un somme :
\\Nature, berce-le chaudement : il a froid.

Les parfums ne font pas frissonner sa narine ;
\\Il dort dans le soleil, la main sur sa poitrine,
\\Tranquille. Il a deux trous rouges au côté droit.

\end{document}
```