# Should I use \\ to end a line or a paragraph?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs

I am somewhat confused as to how to approach  the following issue.

In my thesis is have a lot of text and want to group this is using line breaks and paragraphs.

Up to now I have been using `\\` to end a line and forcibly start a new line as such:

```
some text that is the end of the line want.\\
End than the next line starts at the line below. etc
```

Nothing to worry about.

However if i would like to have some white space ending a paragraph is use the `\\` followed by a white line in my 'code'.

This produces the desired result, however i have lot of underfull vboxes when compiling.
A. is this related to my use of the `\\`?
B. What is the proper way to end/start a paragraph?

I have read about the `\par` command but i am not certain how to apply this...

I use the report documentclass and are going towards a 200 page document so i would like to get this right.

I tried to find the answer in existing posts but was not successful.

Comment: Have you read a starter guide to LaTeX? They will all tell you to separate paragraphs using a blank line, and never using ``\\``.

Comment: See: [When to use `\par` and when `\\\`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when)

Comment: Also, if you want to separate paragraphs by blank lines look at the `parskip` package. (Traditional typography does not do this, using indents instead, but some people prefer blank 'lines'.)

Comment: @JosephWright adding a blank line does not add the white space that i am looking for seperating the two paragraphs. So i will take a look at the parskip package.

Comment: @wierts: The package `parskip` is only useful if you are using a standard document class. E.g. KOMA-classes are providing an extra `parskip` option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In plain text paragraphs in the input file should be separated by a blank line.  To get space between a particular pair of paragraphs in the output you can use `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip`, or the alternatives `\smallbreak`, `\medbreak`, `\bigbreak`, that encourage a page break at such positions.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show
what a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this
text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information?
Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like
‘‘Huardest gefburn’’? Kjift -- not at all! A blind text like this
gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are
written and an impression of the look.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show
what a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this
text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information?
Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like
‘‘Huardest gefburn’’? Kjift -- not at all! A blind text like this
gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are
written and an impression of the look.

\medbreak
Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show
what a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this
text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information?
Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like
‘‘Huardest gefburn’’? Kjift -- not at all! A blind text like this
gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are
written and an impression of the look.

\end{document}
```

If you want spaces between all your paragraphs and no paragraph indent, then you can use the `parskip` package:

[image: Sample parskip output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show
what a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this
text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information?
Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like
‘‘Huardest gefburn’’? Kjift -- not at all! A blind text like this
gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are
written and an impression of the look.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show
what a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this
text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information?
Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like
‘‘Huardest gefburn’’? Kjift -- not at all! A blind text like this
gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are
written and an impression of the look.

\end{document}
```

Using `\\` in plain text it is nearly always wrong, cf. [When to use \par and when \\, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/15925)

Comment: great explication