# Error while displaying bold R \mathbb

Tags: errors, amsmath

Here's my sample code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section*{Problem 1}
Given that : \\
$$ x \epsilon \mathbb{R} (3,2) $$
\end{document}
```

I get the following compilation error when using overleaf :

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.19 $$ x \epsilon \mathbb
                          {R} (3,2) $$
```

How could I fix this ?

Comment: you need to load `amssymb` or `amsfonts`

Comment: Also, `$$ ... $$` is [deprecated](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) in LaTeX

Comment: @Au101 : what should I use in place of `$$...$$` then ?

Comment: `\[ ... \]` follow the hyperlink (click on "deprecated" in my comment) to read more. Also, you shouldn't have the \\, just get rid of it and let `\[ ... \]` handle the skip. Unless you want to start a new paragraph (you probably don't), in which case, leave a blank line

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, but generally speaking, what can be used instead of \\ to skip to a new line ?

Comment: Do this very rarely. Start new paragraphs by leaving a complete blank line. `\\ ` has many legitimate uses, such as in tables, and it does force a line break, but it does not end a paragraph and is rarely needed in the main text. Of course, sometimes you might want it, and in that case, go ahead. It's often used in the `verse` environment for typesetting poetry, for instance. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when, also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136942/should-i-use-to-end-a-line-or-a-paragraph