# Spacing and Margins of Enumeration with Custom Label

Tags: lists, enumitem

I am currently struggling to build an enumeration with custom labels and some adjusted spacings. Afterwords you can find my mwe.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{inner=4cm, outer=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Eine Liste}  
    \begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:, leftmargin=*]
        \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.\\

        Eine ergänzende Information: 1,2,3\\
        Noch eine Info: Test

        \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.\\

        Eine ergänzende Information: 1,2,3\\
        Noch eine Info: Test

    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The mwe looks like this:

[image: mwe with the changes I would like to achieve]

Following you can find the Problems I am facing, which I could not solve:

Red Arrow: The actual text should be a little more seperated from the label. Something like 0.25cm would be nice.

Green Arrow: the distance between the paragraphs should be approximately as big as the blue arrow

Blue Arrow: the distance between items should be approximately as big as the green arrow

In the end the spacing of the green and the blue arrow should be twisted.

To achieve this i played around with the `parsep` and `itemsep` parameters, but I have not been able to achieve my goal.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:, leftmargin=*, parsep=0cm, itemsep=3em]
```

[image: Results after playing with parsep and itemsep]

Is there anybody who has an idea how to achieve these things? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first a remark: Why do you use `\\` before a blank line? You should never do that!

Lets have a look on your three issues:

1. your red arrow: You can get a little bit more space after `:` by for example adding `~` like

   ```
   \begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:~, leftmargin=*] % <============== : -> :~
   ```

   If you need other space check other possibilitys like `\;` etc. instead of `~`.
2. your green arrow: Simply delete the `\\` at the end of the paragraph to get the same distance you get for the blue arrow ...
3. your blue arrow: That is the standard distance between two paragraphs, nothing to do ...

Please see the following corrected MWE for the first list example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  inner=4cm, outer=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\paragraph{Eine Liste}  
\begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:~, leftmargin=*] % <============== : -> :~
  \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.%\\ <===========

    Eine ergänzende Information: 1,2,3\\ % well, better blank line here?
    Noch eine Info: Test

  \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.\\

    Eine ergänzende Information: 1,2,3\\
    Noch eine Info: Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

## EDIT:

To get a bigger space for the green and the blue arrow just see the code for the second example of `enumerate` in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  inner=4cm, outer=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\paragraph{Eine Liste}  
\begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:~, leftmargin=*] % <============== : -> :~  
  \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.%\\ <===========

    Eine ergänzende Information: 1,2,3\\ % well, better blank line here?
    Noch eine Info: Test

  \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.\\

    Eine ergänzende Information: 1,2,3\\
    Noch eine Info: Test
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:~, leftmargin=*, parsep=1cm] % <============== parsep=1cm
  \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
    Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.%\\ <===========

    Eine ergänzende Information: 1,2,3\\ % well, better blank line here?
    Noch eine Info: Test

  \item Hier steht ein Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt. 
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf for mwe two]

Both red arrows show you the result of the added option `, parsep=1cm` in line

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:~, leftmargin=*, parsep=1cm]
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are right. I don't need `\\ ` in this place. Guess I used it in the enumerate environment because I did not know, that it would behave differently compared to plain text. In plain text without `\\ `  I get a new line, but do not get the spacing between the paragraphs. So that helps me about the green arrow. For the blue arrow: Yes, it's the default spacing, but since I have those additional information below the text, i would like to have the different items more sepperated. But this should work with `itemsep`

Comment: Just read this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines Would you advice me, to `\setlength{\parskip}{1.0em}` and use a blank line instead of `\\ ` for my paragraphs?

Comment: If I understand you right, you should use for example `\begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:~, leftmargin=*,parsep=1cm]` and my first example in the enumerated list to get an separated second part (the additional information). Depending on the place you write `\setlength{\parskip}{1.0em}` it can influence all your paragraph distances you really not want. Do not do that!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your updated answer does not really match my needs. I need to have the additional information closer at the item plain text, so that it is obvies that they belong together. And the next item should have a little bit more spacing. But with your help I was able to figure out a way that works for me: `\begin{enumerate}[label=Fall \arabic*:~, leftmargin=*, itemsep=1.5em]` and I removed the '\\ 'after the plain text.

But now I am acutally a little bit confused about usage of `\\ ` in plain text to get a blank line between two paragraphs. Is that "bad TeX"?

Comment: Yes, it is bad TeX to use `\\ ` to get a blank line between paragraphs. To mark the start of a new paragraph always use a blank line, then it depends on the (not) usage of package `parskip`, if that is interpreted/printed as blank line or only an indent ... Please search this site, there is for sure a duplicate to your last comment with the usage of `\\ ` ...

Comment: Yes. I am already googling around for that topic. Thank you. I can actually solve this, with `parskip=1.0em` and replacing `\\ ` by a blank line. But this affects my hack for the new line after `\paragraph`. But in case i don't find a solution for this I will open a new thread.

Comment: See question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136942/should-i-use-to-end-a-line-or-a-paragraph for proper usage of `\\ `