# remove space before and after and table

Tags: tables, spacing

I am new in Latex,so i have seen similar question but none of them work for me.
I have  a table which has a huge margin, or padding before and after it.

I am using [Spring template](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip)
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

Here is some text of mine. Text,Text,Text,Text,

       \begin{table}\addvbuffer[0pt 0pt]
        \centering
        \caption{OCTAVE}
        \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
            \hline
            Evaluation of likelihood &Number of times the event happened in last year  \\ \hline
            Very High & More than three times in a year  \\ \hline
            High & Two or three times in a year  \\ \hline
            Medium & Once in a year \\ \hline
            Low & Three or four times in the last year \\ \hline
            Very Low & one or two times in the last year  \\ \hline    
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

Here is some text of mine. Text,Text,Text,Text,
\end{document}
```

**I need to remove the extra space** between them, and make margin and padding as `0px`.

This [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141757/add-space-before-and-after-tabular-environment) suggests using `addvbuffer[0pt 0pt]`, to control the space
but when i use it as `0pt` it does not change anything

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example, not just sniplets. That question you refer to mentions the package `verbatimbox` of which you mention nothing. Thus we **need** the full minimal example so we can replicate your problem.

Comment: @daleif i have edited my question, i hope this time it is replicable.

Comment: There is no space between the image and the table because there is no image.

Comment: the `llncs` class has a higher space above and below a `h` float than normal classes. This is by design. If you are writing something to be submitted to Springer, leave this setting alone, and in general leave the layout alone. If you mess too much with the layout you'll just end up pissing of the Springer editors who will have to revert your changes back to their design.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a better looking table with only horizontal lines of package `booktabs`. Also the following example reduces the number of packages to a more minimal like example:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

       \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{OCTAVE}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule
            Evaluation of likelihood
            & Number of times the event happened in last year  \\
            \midrule
            Very High & More than three times in a year  \\
            High & Two or three times in a year  \\
            Medium & Once in a year \\
            Low & Three or four times in the last year \\
            Very Low & one or two times in the last year  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The space around the float inside the text body is controlled by length `\intextsep`, which is set in the class file `llncs.cls`:

```
\setlength\intextsep   {8mm\@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
```

(Translated: `8mm plus 2pt minus 2pt`)

If you want to submit a paper to Springer, then I doubt that they are too happy if the submitter changes the layout.

Of course, the length can be minimized to zero as the following, now ugly looking example shows:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\intextsep{0mm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

       \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{OCTAVE}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule
            Evaluation of likelihood
            & Number of times the event happened in last year  \\
            \midrule
            Very High & More than three times in a year  \\
            High & Two or three times in a year  \\
            Medium & Once in a year \\
            Low & Three or four times in the last year \\
            Very Low & one or two times in the last year  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with zero \intextsep]

A compromise, for example, would be half of the space:

```
\setlength\intextsep{\glueexpr\intextsep/2\relax}
```