# Is there an option, within tabularx, to add a vertical whitespace both above and below the table?

Tags: tabularx, white-space

Is there an option within `tabularx` to add a vertical whitespace both above and below the table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {XXX}
 \hline
 item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
 \hline
 item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to add the [`verbatimbox` package which has a service routine `\addvbuffer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141757/add-space-before-and-after-tabular-environment), but it does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\addvbuffer[12pt 8pt]{
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {XXX}
 \hline
 item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
 \hline
 item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDITED after the @David Carlisle answer:**

@David Carlisle, please see here below the errors I get with that solution (might it be something related to Overleaf, that I am using?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\addvbuffer[12pt 8pt]{%%
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {XXX}
 \hline
 item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
 \hline
 item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%%
}
  
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I get the following errors:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When possible, I would like to avoid the usage of ```\vspace```, since I have several tables - And I would like to have the least number of elements to change, in case I need to adjust some spaces in the document.

Comment: `table` environment will add necessary spacing for you; a construct is `\begin{table}[tbh]<tabular env.>\end{table}`. The `[tbh]` are optional parameters for a table placement: `[t]`op, `[b]`ottom, or `[h]`ere. It's also mandatory if you want to add a `\caption{}`.

Comment: I assume one of your 7 errors is that `\addvbuffer` is not defined, which is why `[12pt 8pt]` is typeset as text to the left of the table in your image.

Comment: If the overleaf texlive version is too old, you can contact the support and ask them to move your project to texlive 2024

Comment: Thanks a lot @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I have just contacted the Overleaf Team :-)

Comment: or you can put a newer verbatimbox into your project (I just tried that) but here of course you could simply delete `\addvbuffer` as it's not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you have 7 errors in that file
[image]
so you shouldn't even look at the layout shown in the pdf which can never be relied on after an error.

`tabularx`, like `tabular` does no spacing at all, it is just like a big letter `X` so remove the `\noindent` and replace by (say)

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}... 
...
\end[center}
```

The `center` environment will supply the spacing specified by your documentclass for vertical display constructs.

or in this case place it aroundthe \addvbuffer` (I don't know what that  does)

[image]

note the missing `%` added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\addvbuffer[12pt 8pt]{%%
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {XXX}
 \hline
 item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
 \hline
 item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%%
}
  
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...just in case I need to adjust the vertical distances in an asymmetric way (i.e. the above vertical distance different from the below vertical distance), does the ```center``` environment allow such fine modifications?

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to spin a newenvironment  and can also have a semantic meaning.

Comment: @Ommo not really but you could define a similar environment (which as yannisl just commented is a good idea anyway)

Comment: thanks both for your comments :-)

Comment: @Ommo   just note ethat within the outer environment call the tabularx as `\tabularx` `\endtabularx`. It is all in the manual...

Comment: Sorry @DavidCarlisle, me again.... I have just copied and pasted your code from your answer, and I got some errors, like ```Undefined control sequence.```... I am using Overleaf...could it be the reason?

Comment: @yannisl Thanks, I think I found ```\tabularx``` on page 4 of the manual (https://texdoc.org/serve/tabularx/0)... But I do not understand how to use it... but no problem... thanks for notifying it to me :-)

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle.... I tried your code, but it does not work... did I miss something?

Comment: the code above works and produces the output shown. you must have made an error but I can not guess, you could at least say which command is undefined which the error message will show but which you have not shown here @Ommo

Comment: Thanks for your comments David, please see my EDITED question, where I show the errors I get with your code....

Comment: @Ommo yes you  need a newer package or don't use the package at all, why do you need it? see https://www.overleaf.com/read/pstjcjpthkpn#b1fd9a

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I checked the link you sent me and I can see that that code works there... the textlive 2024? Well, I thought that with that package I could adjust the above and below spaces as I wished...

Comment: @Ommo no look in the overleaf sidebar I uploaded a verbatimbox from an up to date texlive2023 into the project

Comment: Ah ok, thanks :-)