# How can I get rid of space after a tabular, aligned to the right via \hfill?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to get rid of the additional empty space on the right between `\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \textsc{place,} & \textsc{date}\\
    Place, & \today
    \end{tabular} %` and the right page margin/border:

[image]

The title isn't the best I admit, if anyone knows a better one feel free to edit it and this line please.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
a4paper,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
lipsum
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
%\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{flushleft}
Words\\
More Words
\end{flushleft}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
\textsc{code}\\
11-22-33-44
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textsc{place,} & \textsc{date}\\
Place, & \today
\end{tabular}
\begin{flushleft}
\bfseries Words
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Something,
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding a \\ after the `\end{tabular}` seems to do it, along with `@{}` after the `ll`

Comment: you need `@{}` you did it in one table but not the other `\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}` also never do `ar} %` which can put a space after the table in some circumstances, do `ar}%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `l@{}` so the text has no tabcolsep padding on the right (just as you have already used at the left margin in other tables. Then you need to make sure that the `\hfill` is not balanced by the `\parfillskip` glue that is added to the last line of a paragraph. As you want the same effect on both sides, `center` is an appropriate environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
a4paper,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
lipsum
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
Words\\
More Words
\end{flushleft}%
\begin{center}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
\textsc{code}\\
11-22-33-44
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}
\textsc{place,} & \textsc{date}\\
Place, & \today
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}
\bfseries Words
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Something,
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Played around a bit and found

```
\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}
\textsc{place,} & \textsc{date}\\
Place, & \today
\end{tabular}\\
```

works. => **MWE**

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
a4paper,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
lipsum
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
Words\\
More Words
\end{flushleft}%
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
\textsc{code}\\
11-22-33-44
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}
\textsc{place,} & \textsc{date}\\
Place, & \today
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{flushleft}
\bfseries Words
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Something,
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Happy to read other answers, maybe this isn't the only/best solution.

Comment: No. never end a paragraph with `\\ `

Comment: Oh, ok. Well I usually don't but wasn't aware of this "strict" opinion. I was my best next guess.

Comment: I phrased it strictly there to overcome the slight problem that in this case `\\ ` worked rather well:-) But it's a bad habit to get in to and in most circumstances it does the wrong thing. more discussion at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when/82666#82666

Comment: Haha, Isee. :) Was surprised the linked post was relatively short, very interesting, thanks.