# What are the differences between \par\vspace{2cm}\noindent and \\[2cm]?

Tags: spacing, titles

I am designing a titlepage for my report and I am a bit confused in deciding to use either `\par\vspace{2cm}\noindent` or `\\[2cm]` (for example).

Shortly speaking, what are the differences between `\par\vspace{2cm}\noindent` and `\\[2cm]`? When do we have to only use one rather than the other one?

If MWE is really needed, see the following.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\bfseries
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \sffamily Dissertation} \\[15mm]
{\large   ``The simplest proof of the last theorem of Fermat''}\\[5mm]
{\itshape A proof that elementary students can understand}

\vspace{2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{mit-logo}%http://mindenfele.nolblog.hu/files/2014/04/mit_crest_logo.jpg

\vspace{2cm}
{\LARGE \sffamily Donut E. Knot}

\vfill
\begingroup
    \large \sc
    Deparment of Mathematics \\[4mm]
    Massachusetts Institute of Technology \\[4mm]
    Boston, USA \\[4mm]
    2014
\endgroup

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This question might be too basic but I have not understood it because I heavily focus on PSTricks when using LaTeX, as a result, my skill in LaTeX has not significant progress. I am sorry for this inconvenience and thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: This basically boils down to [When to use \par and when \\?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664). But i think on a titlepage, it doesn't matter what to use. But be careful to use real `\par`s in text.

Comment: Not directly relevant here, but `\sc` should be replaced by `\scshape`.

Comment: Why the `center` environment, which has the consequence of not setting the final line at the bottom of the text block? Use `\centering`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the TeX level using `\\` doesn't start a new paragraph while using `\par` obviously does. As noted in comments, [When to use \par and when \\, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when) covers the difference between the two in general. To see what is going on in the current case, where we are talking about 'design', a small demo such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tracingoutput=2
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\noindent
Hello world\\[2cm]
More text
\newpage
\noindent
Hello world\par\vspace{2cm}\noindent
More text
\end{document}
```

is useful. Looking over the log, we see for the first case that between the two parts we have

```
....\penalty 10000
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\penalty -10000
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 56.9055
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 301.63881fil
```

while in the second there is

```
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 56.9055
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 301.63881fil
```

With the standard settings you are not going to see any difference, but if for example `\parfillskip` was set to something for 'special effects' the results could be different. (In the `\\` case, `\hfil` is inserted so will always be `\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil`.) Similarly, notice that using `\par` adds a `\parskip` glue element, which again here is zero length with a small amount of stretch but could be a fixed value: this applies *in addition* to any `\vspace`. (Try `\setlength\parskip{2cm}` to see this.)

As in the more general case of comparing `\par` and `\\` I'd suggest thinking about *meaning*. In the example in the question, the lines manually spaced out are conceptually connected (all part of an address), so `\\` seems more natural than `\par`. The latter is often used *between* different 'blocks' in a title page: the parts are logically separate and often have font differences too.

Comment: The extras added by `\par` probably don't show up in most title pages, but you need to remember that they are there!

Comment: In the `center` environment (and under `\centering` as well), ``\\`` *does* issue `\par`.

Comment: @egreg Reasonable point. I was aiming at the general case, which is what the title has: should I edit or will you post an answer about the possibility of a change down to the environment?

Answer (score 7):

Beware of

```
{\large   ``The simplest proof of the last theorem of Fermat''}\\[5mm]
```

as if the title ended up being more than a line you would have large text set to a normal baseline and inconsistent spacing, size changes should almost always include the end of the paragraph so

```
{\large   ``The simplest proof of the last theorem of Fermat''\par\vspace{5cm}}
```

is better in that case. Outside of a title page (or tables) then any use of `\\` or `\noindent` is usually a sign that something is wrong, so the differences in general don't matter.

Comment: Is there a difference if I remove the `\vspace{5cm}` from the block in your 2nd example above and append it to the following line?

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood no