# Is \\[<len>] as bad as \\ for new lines?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I have heard on multiple occasions that one should rather not use `\\` to force new lines, unless one uses it in environments like `tabular` or `align`, and it is advised to use `\par` instead.

How about starting new lines and creating a given amound of vertical spacing with `\\[<len>]`? Is this macro derived from `\\` and in the same way "bad" for normal text outside of environments? Should I use something like `\par\vspace{<len>}` instead? Or what is the cleanest, and most elegant way of creating lines of text with a fixed vertical spacing?

Thanks!

Comment: It is just as bad to use `\\[1em]`. Use `\par` and set the `parskip` to a reasonable length (which would be something around `\z@`. Please see also [What are the differences between \par\vspace{2cm}\noindent and \\\[2cm\]?]([What are the differences between \par\vspace{2cm}\noindent and \\\[2cm\]?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198310)) and [When to use \par and when \\?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Comment: `\\` is only "bad" because explicit line breaking and spacing is generally "bad" (or at least shouldn't be done in general documents) so `\\[..]` and `\par\vspace` are equally `bad`

Comment: the phrasing here isn't optimally clear.  the double backslash is only bad if it is used instead of a paragraph break.  if you're using it to break a line in order to start the next line with something in particular, for example a url that you want to highlight, that's entirely reasonable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd use a display for the url (you definitely want more indentation). For technical writing an unnumbered list with a single entry is also perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen -- good points.  what i was trying to say (not very well, i guess) is that it's okay to use a double backslash to end a line if something other than a new paragraph, a blank line, or a display comes next. possibly better example: breaking the lines of a poem or an address.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Another good reason for using `\\[..]` is when you want to override the defaul line distance inside a `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 9):

For one-off spacing changes,
`\smallskip`, `\medskip`, and `\bigskip` are defined for this task.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\TestSkip[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
    \raggedright
    This is some dummy text.

    #1

    This is some dummy text.
  \end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\TestSkip{}
\TestSkip{\smallskip}
\TestSkip{\medskip}
\TestSkip{\bigskip}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

After rereading the question, I'll note that these aren't 'fixed' spaces; they're rubber lengths (defined according to `\smallskipamount`, etc.) and will shrink/expand according to the amount of available vertical space when the page is being built.

```
$ texdef smallskip smallskipamount medskipamount bigskipamount

\smallskip:
macro:->\vskip \smallskipamount 


\smallskipamount:
\skip13


\the\smallskipamount:
3.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt


\medskipamount:
\skip14


\the\medskipamount:
6.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt


\bigskipamount:
\skip15


\the\bigskipamount:
12.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 4.0pt
```