# Define amount of space after \newline, \\, or \linebreak

Tags: spacing, formatting, line-breaking

How do I define the amount of vertical space there are after all new lines? I am looking for something that works like this:

```
\define{x = 4}

blah blah blah blah \\[x pt]
blah blah \\[x pt]
```

Where I can with one modification change the amount of vertical space after all new lines. I don't care whether it uses \\, \newline, \linebreak, or something else.

Comment: You should try your guess :) But don't break lines with \newline, or double backslash etc. The actual definition is `\def\myvar{4}` then your code follows

Comment: @TokeFaurby You should avoid \\ or `\\[<length>]` to start a new line. See  this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198824/is-len-as-bad-as-for-new-lines  and this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when?lq=1  and also this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198299/what-are-the-differences-between-par-vspace2cm-noindent-and-2cm?lq=1 for more discussions on this.