# Line break that doesn't work cumulative?

Tags: line-breaking

I'm looking for a way to write a macro that will add a line break after the text from the argument, but prevent that line break to add to another line break, if there is one following.

If I use `\newcommand*\ask[1]{{\bf Q:} #1 \\}` and then use `\ask{How?} \\` I will have used two `\\` and thus get two vertical spaces. But I just want one line break, no further vertical space. The same holds for `\newline`, `\\*` and `\hfill\break`.

Sorry, if my description sounds confusing, I may not have used the proper LaTeX terms. I hope you understand my question anyway.

Comment: `\\ ` should almost never be used outside of tables. use `\par` (or equivalently a blank line) also `\textbf{G}`  (`\bf` is just for compatibility with the 1908's version of latex and is not defined by default in the latex format)

Comment: this is related (possibly duplicate) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sometimes misprints are so nice... 1908's version of latex ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke it seems a long time ago:-)

Comment: The `Q` is presumably a heading of sorts in which case you should probably use a heading or list item command (which would automatically have the effect you want of ignoring any following blank lines) `\section*{Q}xxx` and `\section*{Q} <blank line> xxx` are typeset the same way

Comment: No, I need this macro to place comments in a document. By defining the macro as ``{}`` I can make the comments disappear and can create a different version of said document.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `\\` in documents outside of tabular and math environments.

```
\newcommand*\ask[1]{\section*{Q: #1}}
```

Probably does the right thing (or you may want a different level or a custom heading command using the same `\@startsection` base layout as the sectioning commands).

Then

```
\ask{something}blah blah
```

and

```
\ask{something}

blah blah
```

Will have the same layout, with the linebreak after the `\ask` not having any affect on the output.