# How to increase the space between text and a table?

Tags: tables, line-spacing

Here is my code:

```
Volume of the hall V = 1500 $m^3$ \\
\noindent \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
\hline
\textit{Surface} & \textit{Area ($m^2)$} & \textit{Coefficient of absorption}\\
\hline
ceiling & 140 & 0.8 \\
\hline
walls & 260 & 0.03 \\
\hline
floor & 140 & 0.06 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

This code results in a table that is very close to the text. I want to increase the space to at least 2cm. I tried adding a double line break too. It threw back some kind of hbox error. please help.

Comment: Adding a `\bigskip` before \\ on your first line may be what you want. Alternatively you can use `\vspace{2cm}` if you want to precisely choose how much space should be in between. Yet another alternative is to place the tabular in a `\begin{center}`/`\end{center}` environment, which centers the table but also adds some appropriate space.

Comment: You could use an environment, that adds some white space above and below itselve, for example. `\begin{ccenter}<table>\end{center}` and maybe a minipage in between.

Comment: Just in case, please have a look at [When to use \par and when \\?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Comment: One question that remains: Why aren't you using a `table` environment? Do you want the table prevent from floating and have it typeset Iexactly at this place*? Do you need captions for your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set vertical space with `\vspace{2cm}`.
I personally think that the standard space provided is quite pleasing, your opinion might differ.
I've updated your code snippet to a full example, also adding some things which I think are good practices (as suggested by @Yori in the comments).

- I'm using the middle-european [KOMA script class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), which has a global `parskip` option, taking care of both indentation and skipping of paragraphs.
- The `siunitx` package helps with typesetting SI units (and aligning numbers in the table with the `S` column specifier)
- `booktabs` enhances the quality of the table presentation (read it's manual for some insight).
- `blindtext` helps to fill the page and
- `hyperref` makes for nice referencing.

I'm fully aware that your opinion might differ, but I think the table/text combination look good like that.
If you'd like to change it, you can comment line 1, uncomment lines 2--4 and play with the `\vspace{2cm}` option until you get a result that pleases your eyes.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass{article}
%\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%\setlength\parskip{10pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

Volume of the hall \(V = \SI{1500}{\cubic\metre}\), details can be found in \autoref{tab:hall details}.

%\vspace{2cm}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Details of the hall}
    \label{tab:hall details}
    \begin{tabular}{ccS}
        \toprule
        Surface & Area (\si{\metre\squared}) & {Coefficient of absorption}\\
        \midrule
        ceiling & 140 & 0.8 \\
        walls & 260 & 0.03 \\
        floor & 140 & 0.06 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1 for adding in some best practices. It's probably good to explain what you did though. For example, why did you use `booktabs` instead?

Comment: `[h]` does not make sure, that the table stays there for good. What happens if the table is floated to another page with the `vspace`?

Comment: If `parindent` is set to zero, `parskip` should differ from zero to visually clarify the beginning of a new paragraph in the output.

Comment: @Yori: Good idea, I'll add that.
@Johannes_B: I didn't think about the floating to another page, since I never™ use it myself. Does [h!] take care of that? And I definitely agree on the `parskip` issue, which I've added to the example.

Comment: @Habi `[h!]` is not good. If such a float can't be placed “here” or ”top” (the `t` is automatically added), it will block the float queue.

Comment: @egreg As I've said, I personally only use `[htb]`, but @Johannes_B seems to not have liked my `[h]` suggestion. How else can one make sure that the "table stays there for good"?

Comment: @Habi Murphy’s law will come into action as soon as you seem to have succeeded into having a table “precisely there”: you (or someone else, your supervisor, for instance) will immediately realize that a couple of paragraphs before the table need to be modified and, of course, there will be no space for the table “there”. Start with a different attitude: let the floats float.

Comment: @egreg I'm all for floating and only™ use the `[htb]` placement for final versions :) Soumya wanted to specify precisely "here"...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the lenght of the line break with  `\\[2cm]` but I would use another approach that  manually increase the spacing in this way. The same apply to  alternative commands as `\vspace{2cm}`, `\bigskip`, etc to add a specific space.

In order to obtain a consistent format across the the pages, ideally you must try to set all your format preferences in the preamble and avoid messing your text with low format code.  For example, you can modify globally as you want the paragraph skip, so that the table is spaced as any paragraph simply adding a blank line (`\par`). If you prefer mora spacing between text and tables than among the paragraphs, you can also set a different space around a  `table` float, as well as the spacing between the caption and the table, if ther are one (it is not clear in your example if the line above the table is the caption).

Example to play with global spacing:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5cm} % change this length as you want 
\setlength{\intextsep}{1cm plus .1cm minus 1.cm} % change this length as you want
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{.2cm} % change this length as you want
\begin{document}

Text before tabular   

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
\textit{Surface} & \textit{Area ($m^2)$} & \textit{Coefficient of absorption}\\
\hline
ceiling & 140 & 0.8 \\
walls & 260 & 0.03 \\
floor & 140 & 0.06 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Text after tabular % test space between paragraph

Text before float

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Volume of the hall V = 1500 $m^3$.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
\textit{Surface} & \textit{Area ($m^2)$} & \textit{Coefficient of absorption}\\
\hline
ceiling & 140 & 0.8 \\
walls & 260 & 0.03 \\
floor & 140 & 0.06 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Text after float

\end{document}
```

May be enough?

(Note that many people hate the excess of vertical and horizontal rules. I also suggest  `booktabs` commands instead of `\hline` for better results.)