# Increasing space between paragraphs

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I want to know how to increase the distance between two paragraphs but not between two lines of the same paragraph. 
For example, if I type a long line, I want to wrap that line into a paragraph, but when I deliberately press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or type `\\` and begin another paragraph, I want the default distance to be higher. Is it possible to set this for the whole document without using `\\[10pt]`?

Comment: `\\ ` does _not_ begin a new paragraph!

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when

Answer (score 3):

This is obtained by setting nonzero `\parskip`, e.g. `\parskip10pt`. Please keep in mind that such paragraphs should not be indented (you should set `\parindent0pt`), because mixing these two is considered a bad style.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I have been trying to figure that out since whole night, thanks alot!!