# Vertically align two separate TikZ figures below each other using the subfig package

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

The following minimal working example does not vertically align two rectangles drawn by TikZ. The result can be found [here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/253976080/Horizontal-Alignment?secret_password=tQA65N2vlaUioAwEAjln). Somehow the second rectangle seems bolded, but that is not the case when I open the .pdf on my PC.

I would like the two rectangles to be vertically aligned and centered (which is equivalent to both centering them). Why is the second rectangle indented?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.11}

\newcommand{\rect}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}%

\begin{figure}%
\centering%
\subfloat[First rectangle.]{\rect}%
\newline%
\subfloat[Second rectangle.]{\rect}%
\caption{This is a figure with two rectangles that do not horizontally align.}
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just found out that if I replace the following part `\subfloat[First rectangle.]{\rect}%
\newline%` by `\subfloat[First rectangle.]{\rect}\\%`, then it works. Can someone explain why?

Comment: May be http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82666/1952 helps you to understand it

Comment: Don't use `\newline` but `\par`.

Comment: Instead of `\newline`, you should use `\par` or ` \\ `; `\centering` redefines ` \\ ` so it behaves well; however, `\newline` keeps its definition as `\@normalcr\relax` (which is essentially the "normal" definition of  ` \\ ` ) and this produces bad results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second rectangle is not indented, the first one is not really centered and this is not due to the `subfig` package nor to the use of figures created using TikZ.

The problem here is that, inside `\centering` (`\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` and similar), `\newline` behaves as the "normal" `\\` which is basically `\@normalcr\relax` and this produces undesired behaviours illustrated in the example below. `\centering` redefines `\\` (but `\newline` keeps its standard definition) to (essentially) `\par\addvspace{-\parskip}` so when using `\centering` (`\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` and similar) you should use `\\` or `\par` but no `\newline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,a6paper]{geometry}% just for visualization purposes

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
Center \\
Center \par
Center?
\newline 
Center
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your example code using `\par` and `\\`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\rect{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[First rectangle.]{\rect}
\par
\subfloat[Second rectangle.]{\rect} 
\\
\subfloat[Third rectangle.]{\rect}
\caption{This is a figure with three rectangles horizontally aligned}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: @krnl as I mentioned in my answer, inside `\centering`, the ` \\ ` command is redefined to be `\par` plus a possible skip of `-\parskip`. In standard settings you can use either one.

Comment: And how can I make the captions as `Fig. 1-(a) First rectangle` , `Fig. 1-(b) Second rectangle` and `Fig. 1-(c) Third rectangle` without the final caption?

Comment: @AboAmmar Please feel free to open follow-up question.

Comment: How do you make them underneath each other, but on the left?