# Error: \item is invalid in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I would like to put a vertical bar in my regex expression but I keep getting an error when I put in `\mid`. Can you help?

```
\item \textbf{Give a regular expression for the language accepted by the automaton~$A$.} \\\\
(0 \mid 1)*01)0 \mid 1)*\\
 \item \textbf{Explain what makes the automaton~$A$ non-deterministic.}\\\\
 The reason automaton~$A$ is non-deterministic is because in the state q0 reading a 0 can either lead to $q_0$ or $q_1$.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The command `\mid` *must* appear in math mode and it produces errors in normal text modes.

Comment: And please learn *not* to use ``\\`` in the text, ever!

Comment: @daleif Mind explaining why? I'm quite new to using latex.

Comment: @egreg is there a way I can do a vertical bar in text mode

Comment: First of, ``\\\\` give an underfull hbox badness 10000. In general you should never have any need to insert manual line breaks. Of you do, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @rembrandt, that looks more like math, not text.

Comment: There is a `\textbar` macro to typeset a vertical bar in textmode. I'd just put the regex in math mode though: `\[(0 \mid 1)*01)0 \mid 1)*\]` (removing the `\\`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\mid` causes tex to switch into math mode, and it's still in math mode when it gets to the next `\item`, hence the unexpected error message.

instead of what you have, make the line with `\mid` an unnumbered math display:

```
\item \textbf{Give a regular expression for the language accepted by the automaton~$A$.}
\[ (0 \mid 1)*01)0 \mid 1)* \]
 \item \textbf{Explain what makes the automaton~$A$ non-deterministic.}

 The reason automaton~$A$ is non-deterministic is because in the state $q_0$ reading a $0$
 can lead to either $q_0$ or $q_1$.
```

using double backslashes, as already commented, is not a good practice.  see 
[When to use \par and when `\\`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)
for more information.

**edit:** based on a comment about what is math and what isn't, i've adjusted the original
code; i've also applied my "editing pencil" to the position of "either" for clarity.
(apologies for my presumption; see my user profile to understand why i'm fussy this way.)

Comment: PS I think the `q0` in the next to last line should be `$q_0$`. Technically, even the `0` should be `$0$`.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, thank you for noticing that.