# question in latex

Tags: paragraphs, syntax

`\\` command in latex creates a new paragraph. I want a command in which when I finish a line, I want to have next line black and then I want to start from the left of next line. Is there an easy command for this.

Example:
What I want:

```
'I wrote something here

I want to start from here'
```

What I do not want :

```
'I wrote something here

    command in latex  starts from here, with gap in the left'
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid your question is not very clear. Can you add some more details?

Comment: black or blank? The question is somehow contradictory

Comment: `\noindent` after an empty line starts a new paragraph without indentation. If you want to have space between paragraphs without paragraph indentation, see package `parskip`.

Comment: Also important, ``\\`` in LaTeX *does not* start a new paragraph. If you want to start a new paragraph, as Heiko says, leave a blank line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\setlength\parindent{0pt} \setlength\parskip{1ex}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use \par and when \∖](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default with the standard classes are paragraphs, whose first lines are indented and without additional space inbetween:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result parindent, no parskip]

Package `parskip` adds space between paragraphs and the paragraphs start without indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with parskip, no parindent]

In TeX paragraphs are ended by an empty line (which triggers an `\par` command).
`\\` is mainly used in tables (environment `tabular`), or where explicit line breaks are needed. `\\` at the end of a paragraph (before an empty line) is an error. TeX has broken the line to start a new one, but there is nothing causing an underfull `\hbox` warning.