# New line avoiding errors and following WYSIWYM philosophy

Tags: formatting, line-breaking

I understand that using `\\` is not a good idea. It's better to use just the "enter" key or the `\par` command.
Anyway, I don't like what I get. I would like to have a blank line between two pieces of text all over my text, where I want. Something like this:

```
...some text here.

Some othe text here...
```

I noticed that `\par~\par` does the job. Is a good practice to use this? I was also wondering if I can define my own command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\nl}{\par~\par}
```

so that I can use `\nl` at the end of the text.

Is this good or there are some pitfalls here?

Comment: This is a very bad way to go.  Look instead at the `parskip` package.

Comment: Most definitely _not good_. If you want to signal a paragraph break in the typeset ouput with an empty line instead of indentation, have a look to the `parskip` package or equivalent options provided by certain "heavyweight" document classes. (Edit: ninja'd by jon... :-))

Comment: Ha, by like two seconds....

Comment: I don't get any "badness" warnings from the compiler. So why not? What is the problem? I want to understand please.

Comment: Think about what will happen if this "paragraph" falls at a page break, for one: you'll get extra space at either the bottom or the top of the page.

Comment: It's an example of 'ad hoc' markup, which is totally unmaintainable in general.  If you want a 'global' design setting, use a command in the preamble and then input the document as you normally would.  The `parskip` package fills that need in your case.

Comment: Note that if you need this between certain text blocks but not all paragraphs, rather than using `parskip`, you can put e.g. `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip` before the blank line (or `\par`) to insert extra spacing. This is much better than `\par~\par` but should nonetheless be used with caution since it is less maintainable and makes it harder to achieve consistent formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer in Math.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX excels at laying out a page with well-formed paragraphs, so let the program do what it does best. Leave a blank line between paragraphs in your source code. TeX interprets the blank line as a `\par` instruction, so you don't need to write that command explicitly. The `\\` command is simply not intended for use in ordinary text; instead it is used in `tabular` and `verse` environments, among others.

If you want to use white space as an occasional section break, then you could define `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}` in the preamble and then just write `\sectionbreak` in the document where you need it. (You can also use larger values like `2\baselineskip` or you could use the commands `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`.)

```
...end of paragraph.

\sectionbreak

Next paragraph...
```

If you want white space between every paragraph as part of the design of your document, then really you want to increase the value of `\parskip`, but doing that manually can cause problems because TeX relies on there being a certain amount of "glue" to adjust between vertically stacked boxes in order to lay out the page. Instead, you can simply write `\usepackage{parskip}` and the package will adjust the values properly. In the `memoir` class, there is a `\nonzeroparskip` command that does something similar.

In a least-optimal scenario (because it doesn't separate content from presentation and locks you into a particular layout), if you have a short series of text lines which you would like separated by white space, you can use a `tabular` environment. You can use `\\[1ex]` at the end of the line to get an extra blank line. (With the `booktabs` package you can just write `\addlinespace`.)

```
\begin{tabular}{l} 
First line\\[1ex] 
Second line\\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when