# Referencing formula before defining it

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm writing a scientific article and I would like to reference a formula before it appears in the text. In principle it should work, the problem is that I want to use the hyperref package, so that I can create a hyperlink to that formula. This is the code I'm using:

```
F is defined in Formula \ref{eq:Fdef} \\

\begin{equation} \label{eq:Fdef}
F = RU
\end{equation}
```

If I use \usepackage{hyperref} at the beginning of the document I obtain the following error:

! Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.

I thought that maybe there was some way of defining the equation before, but including it in the text later, but I didn't find how to do it, any suggestion?

Comment: Please complete your code with the document class and a minimal set of packages used. That way it's easier for people here to spot the problem.

Comment: Getting rid of the \\ will fix it (even with `hyperref`).  You shouldn't be using \\ in normal text, in any event, or it will tend to produce the wrong vertical spacing,  Just leave a blank line for a new paragraph (or not).

Comment: also better not to leave a blank line before a math display.  that takes the spacing out of latex's control by making it look like the beginning of a paragraph.  the spacing above and below displays is cooked into latex, but only if it's not avoided by extra blank lines in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is obtained by removing the `\\` from the line, following the `\ref`.

As I commented, the use of `\\` is specialized for things like `tabular` and should generally be avoided in normal text.  See David's answer at [When to use \par and when \\, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when) for a better discussion.

I don't know what `hyperref` did to actually make the code break by placing a `\\` immediately following a `\ref`, but since it is bad LaTeX to use it, good grammar takes care of the problem.

As barbara adds, an `equation` environment is generally not preceded by a paragraph break.

And, as egreg adds, the "F" in the text should be `$F$` to place it in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
$F$ is defined in Formula \ref{eq:Fdef}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:Fdef}
F = RU
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should also use `$F$` before “is defined”.

Comment: Yet another hint from `hyperref`'s README: Consider using the
environments that package amsmath provide, e.g. gather for equation.
The environment equation can even redefined to use gather:
`\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\equation\gather
\let\endequation\endgather`