# Best practice for writing. Oneliner? Enter key? \\? \newline?

Tags: formatting, sourcecode

I just started using LaTeX to write my bachelor thesis and everything is already set up and working (took 2 weeks but it is finally done). I was just starting to write a chapter and am wondering what would be the best or recommended way to actually write?

I am using TeXstudio and I like to use the enter key to sort my text into parts, not section or similar. Just for "visual". 
And I also prefer to use double enter key to make a break. 
As a result my text is not all on one single line, for example at the moment line 13 contains my whole chapter 1.

But now I read that one should prefer to use `\\` or `\newline` instead of enter. Doing so would hinder my need for a "visual separation".

As you may have guessed I come from a word background so that is probably my problem here.

I would like to know what is the preferred way to write in this case? Kill my habits from word and just deal with huge oneliner? double enter key? `\\`? `\newline`?

Comment: Don't use double bars neither `\newline`. Since you are a beginner, just type and hit ENTER with you want to make the code more readable. For TeX, it doesn't matter. But to start a new real paragraph on the text (I mean, after compilation) leave **at least one** blank line in the code. You can see a simple example of code here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199816/19195 Note how TeXstudio treats the line numbers.

Comment: Empty line is the proper way to go.  Do NOT use \\ as line or paragraph separator if it can be avoided.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when

Comment: There are some other posts that ask similar questions, if you search around... my preference is 1 sentence per line, so that version control with Git is easy. Note that a blank line will lead to a paragraph break, and you should not use `\\\` except in special circumstances.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the question in Stephen's comment, but as a general rule (which you can break sometimes, but not as a beginner:-) is never use `\\ ` outside of tables and alignments and never use `\newline`

Comment: note that a single newline is the same as a space so there is never a reason to put a whole chapter on one line, you can break the line arbitrarily short changing any space to a newline in the source does not change the output.

Comment: Thank you guys. That helped a lot. Off topic but why is this a duplicate? I am clearly asking about all other options and a general advice and not when to use par or \\. Well \\ is included but still I don't see the duplicate. But my question is answered to everything is good. :)