# What is a primitive, a macro, and how do they compare?

Tags: macros, primitives

The title pretty much says it all.  If it helps, I found myself asking this question when reading [this post about \par vs. \\](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not so short answer (too long for a comment), but not really 
long on the other hand.

TeX primitives are the `elementary particles` of TeX Universe. They are not and can't be constructed of other command sequences. Those primitives are given already by the TeX engine and are not defined in `plain.tex` (or in `latex.ltx` for the LaTeX version). These days, the most commonly used TeX engines are pdftex, xetex, and luatex.

A macro, in contrast, is set up using TeX primitives (such as `\def`) and/or other macros which, in turn, use still other primitives. You can find macros in the file `plain.tex` (the Plain-TeX core), in `latex.ltx` (the LaTeX kernel), as well as in various `.cls` and `.sty` package files and `inline` in many documents.

Prominent primitives are `\let`, `\par`, `\box`, `\hskip`, `\vskip`, `\def` (and its variants `\edef` etc.), `\expandafter` etc. The list is too long to name all here.

It is, in principle, possible to redefine `\par` via `\def\par{...}`, for example. However, this is not advisable in most cases. Use `\let\oldpar\par` to save the meaning of `\par` before doing something weird to the TeX system ;-)

Common to both primitives and macros is that they are command sequences which sometimes have arguments.

Answer (score 21):

TeX is a macro-expansion language. That means that what we can define as programmers is a series of macros which get replaced at point-of use by their definition. Thus with

```
\def\foo{\baz ab}
```

when I use `\foo` TeX replaces it with `\baz ab` then looks a `\baz` to find what it is defined as. That might be another macro, it might be some literal text (such as the `ab`) or it might be a *primitive*. That's a command that is built-in to TeX and so is executed rather than expanded. Thus for example the `\par` primitive is an instruction to TeX to do some typesetting.

There are a few provisos to the above. First, we can define names that are the same as primitives

```
\let\oldfpar\par
\def\par{...
```

which can be used for various effects. That is an important technique, but notice I've saved the original form so I can still get at the primitive.

Secondly, whilst I've said that primitives are executed, some of them are 'expandable' and so do get replaced in some way by a 'result'. The `\par` primitive isn't one of those (typesetting can't be thought of as 'providing a replacement text), but for example all of the conditionals (`\if...`) are.

Thirdly, we can create control sequences ('commands') which are not macros. We've already seen `\let`, which copies a control sequence meaning to a new name so can be used for primitives as well as macros. We can also do things like `\chardef`, which makes a control sequence equal to a character or rather to a character number.

You can see what the current definition of something is using `\show`. So with

```
\show\par
\let\oldpar\par
\def\par{\oldpar}
\show\par
```

I get

```
> \par=\par.
l.1 \show\par

? 
> \par=macro:
->\oldpar .
l.4 \show\par
```

Notice in the first case I have the control sequence `\par` equal to the primitive `\par`, whilst in the second case it's a macro. That can lead to some odd effects:

```
\let\savedshow\show
\let\show\par
\let\par\savedshow
\par\show
\par\par
```

yields

```
> \show=\par.
l.4 \par\show

? 
> \par=\show.
l.5 \par\par

?
```

The key point here is that the 'internal' name of the primitive (the name TeX uses for the action it means) never changes.