# Question on where `plus` primitive is defined

Tags: tex-core

I often see either `\@plus` and `plus` when specifying the stretchiness of a glue (skip).
I can see that `\@plus` is the same command as `plus` from `latex.ltx` (the line `\def\@plus{plus}`).

But I don't see any `plus` identified as a tex primitive [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TeX_primitives_listed_by_TeX_engine) nor do I see it described in `plain.tex`. So what it is? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Related: [What is a primitive, a macro, and how do they compare?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267980/5764)

Comment: By the way, for these things you can lookup by looking up the documentation of the corresponding macro (for example `hskip` that comes before the thing, then note that it takes a `<glue>` as argument, then after that lookup what glue means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`plus` is not a primitive itself it (along with `minus`) is part of the syntax of a glue (skip) length. Similar to the usage of `pt` or `cm` which similarly are keywords used in length syntax.

The TeXBook gives the list of such keywords in classical, unextended TeX as

> Here is a complete list of TeX's keywords, in case you are wondering about
> the full set: `at`, `bp`, `by`, `cc`, `cm`, `dd`, `depth`, `em`, `ex`,
> `fil`, `height`, `in`, `l`, `minus`, `mm`, `mu`, `pc`, `plus`,
> `pt`, `scaled`, `sp`, `spread`, `to`, `true`, `width`.
> (See Appendix~I for references to the contexts in which each of these is
> recognized as a keyword.)

So it is defined in the web sources of tex-the-program, specifically the code that scans a glue specification:

```
@ @<Create a new glue specification whose width is |cur_val|...@>=
q:=new_spec(zero_glue); width(q):=cur_val;
if scan_keyword("plus") then
@.plus@>
  begin scan_dimen(mu,true,false);
  stretch(q):=cur_val; stretch_order(q):=cur_order;
  end;
if scan_keyword("minus") then
@.minus@>
  begin scan_dimen(mu,true,false);
  shrink(q):=cur_val; shrink_order(q):=cur_order;
  end;
cur_val:=q
```