What is "\in@" and how is it used?
what does \in@ do ? is it a primitive command reserved by Tex ? Seems it is uesed to check if a text is a part of another text.

It is not TeX primitive. It's definition can be found in latex.ltx, i.e. it is something relevant with LaTeX macros. TeX primitives have names without @ by default (in iniTeX state).

for any command you can see if it is a primitive, or what its definition is using \show\@in

In my environment \show\@in says \@=udefined (i.e. @ isn't letter) and \ea\show \csname @in\endcsname says \@in=\relax (i.e. it was undefined before \csname..\endcsname and of course, it isn.t TeX primitive :). But how it is defined in LaTeX can be shown by this way only if LaTeX macro is used (which isn't my case).

For the question about primitive see also Joseph's answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267980/what-is-a-primitive-a-macro-and-how-do-they-compare.

@wipet Why are you testing \show\@in instead of \show\in@ (which also needs \makeatletter)? Simply try latex '\makeatletter\show\in@' (quoting for usage in a linux shell, with Windows you may have to adapt it).

OK, I misspelled \in@ and wrote \@in. Again: In my environment \show\in@ says \in=\mathchar"3232., i.e. @ isn't letter and \in is declared by \mathchardef. And \ea\show \csname in@\endcsname says \in@=\relax, i.e it was undefined before \csname..\endcsname and of course, it isn.t TeX primitive :).  How it is defined in LaTeX can be shown by this way only if LaTeX macros is pre-loaded (which isn't my case).

@wipet Once again: \in@ is an internal macro, so \show\in@ needs \makeatletter. BTW: \csname foo\endcsname always makes an undefined \foo to be \relax. So you using \expandafter\show\csname foo\endcsname cannot be used to show, whether \foo is defined or not.

Despite Joseph already has shown how to distinguish primitives and macros in the answer I've linked above, another valid primitive test should be tex --ini --interaction nonstopmode '\catcode`\@=11 \show\in@\bye' (once again quoting for linux shell).

@cabohah You are not true. \csname foo\endcsname sets \foo to relax only if it was undefined before this action. So, it can be used to show, whether \foo is defined or not. And moreover, in my environment I never use \makeatleter because it is undefined control sequence. It is defined only in LaTeX.

@wipet Sorry, but you once again did not read carefully: I already wrote “makes an undefined \foo to be \relax”. I never told, that it makes all \foo \relax. And \expandafter\show\csname foo\endcsname cannot distinguish a \foo which is \relax and a \foo which is undefined. And I've also shown how to replace \makeatletter outside LaTeX.

@wipet BTW: ”My environment” is very unspecific. For example in texinfo @ is, what \ would be in plainTeX or LaTeX. So nobody knows the catcode of @ in your environment. If you have a question about how to show the definition of \in@ in your environment you should specify your environment. Nevertheless, in several environments {\catcode`\@=11\show\in@} should work. See my above comment about how to do the test from the command line. But if you still have a question for your specific environment, please ask it as new question.

@cabohah I have no question. You take things too seriously. I tried to make a joke and to point out that there is no LaTeX only. The fact that \in@ isn't TeX primitive can be shown outside LaTeX too. For example in my environment https://petr.olsak.net/optex/. If you don't know what it is, you can click.

latexdef \in@ works for me. simpler and more effective ....

Adding to campa's fine answer, this is how it can be done with TeX primitives.
Note that the order of arguments is not reversed.
\def\isin#1#2#3{\def\tmp##1#1##2\end{\ifx\end##2\end\expandafter\unless\fi#3}\tmp#2#1\end}

\isin {d} {abcde}             \iftrue Y\else N\fi \par
\isin {foo} {bar,baz}         \iftrue Y\else N\fi \par
\isin {foo} {foobar,bar,baz}  \iftrue Y\else N\fi \par
\isin {,foo,} {,foo,bar,baz,} \iftrue Y\else N\fi \par

\bye


+1 very nice \unless trick!

From the LaTeX documented source (texdoc source2e)

\@in is a utility macro with two arguments. It determines whether its first argument occurs in its second and sets the switch \ifin@ accordingly. The first argument may not contain braces nor # (more precisely, tokens of category code 1, 2, or 6).

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\in@{d}{abcde}\ifin@ Y\else N\fi,
\in@{foo}{bar,baz}\ifin@ Y\else N\fi,
\in@{foo}{foobar,bar,baz}\ifin@ Y\else N\fi,
\in@{,foo,}{,foo,bar,baz,}\ifin@ Y\else N\fi
\end{document}


It is not a primitive:
\def\in@#1#2%
 {%
   \begingroup
     \def\in@@##1#1{}%
     \toks@\expandafter{\in@@#2{}{}#1}%
     \edef\in@@{\the\toks@}%
   \expandafter\endgroup
   \ifx\in@@\@empty
     \in@false
   \else
     \in@true
   \fi
 }
\newif\ifin@


Adding to campa's fine answer, this is how it can be done with modern tools:
\tl_if_in:nnTF {abcde} {d} { YES } { NO }

Note that the order of arguments is reversed.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_if_in:nnTF {abcde} {d} {Y} {N} \par

\tl_if_in:nnTF {bar,baz} {foo} {Y} {N} \par

\tl_if_in:nnTF {foobar,bar,baz} {foo} {Y} {N} \par

\tl_if_in:nnTF {,foo,bar,baz,} {,foo,} {Y} {N} \par

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


