# How to use amsmath environment \Bmatrix inside a glossary?

Tags: amsmath, glossaries

I´d like to use the following environment from amsmath-package for a glossary-entry but latex fails (TexStudio with pdflatex):

\begin{Bmatrix}...\end{Bmatrix}

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{glossaries}
%
\begin{document}
\section{in Textmode everything is fine}
$\begin{Bmatrix}W_{ij}\end{Bmatrix}$, brackets with the required height
%
\section{trying the same using glossaries}
%
the working one:\par
%
\newglossaryentry{mat:Wij}{%
name=\ensuremath{\left\{W_{ij}\right\}},
description={working entry, tensor brackets manually}
}%
%
\gls{mat:Wij}, Problem: brackets don´t have the required height\\
\\ 
%%
the one with the following mistake:\par
line 30: Undefined control sequence. \} \\  
%
%\newglossaryentry{mat:Mij}{%
%name=\ensuremath{
%\begin{Bmatrix}
%M_{ij}
%\end{Bmatrix}},
%description={entry with mistake, tensor brackets by Bmatrix-command}
%}%
%%
%\gls{mat:Mij}, brackets with the required height
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a MWE. Incidentally you might want to look at [When to use `\par` and when ``\\``](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by [expansion](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion).

Working version:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\glsnoexpandfields

\newglossaryentry{mat:Mij}{%
name=\ensuremath{
\begin{Bmatrix}
M_{ij}
\end{Bmatrix}},
description={entry with mistake, tensor brackets by Bmatrix-command}
}

\newglossaryentry{mat:Wij}{%
name=\ensuremath{\left\{W_{ij}\right\}},
description={working entry, tensor brackets manually}
}%

\begin{document}
\section{in Textmode everything is fine}
$\begin{Bmatrix}W_{ij}\end{Bmatrix}$, brackets with the required height

\section{trying the same using glossaries}

the working one:


\gls{mat:Wij}, Problem: brackets don´t have the required height

the one with the following mistake:\par
line 30: Undefined control sequence. \}  

\gls{mat:Mij}, brackets with the required height
\end{document}
```

I recommend you [move your definitions to the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) (as I've done above). If you really want them in the document use

```
\usepackage[docdefs=restricted]{glossaries-extra}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

If you intend to add `\printglossaries`, remember to add the `sort` key for those entries:

```
\newglossaryentry{mat:Mij}{%
sort={Mij},
name=\ensuremath{
\begin{Bmatrix}
M_{ij}
\end{Bmatrix}},
description={entry with mistake, tensor brackets by Bmatrix-command}
}

\newglossaryentry{mat:Wij}{%
sort={Wij},
name=\ensuremath{\left\{W_{ij}\right\}},
description={working entry, tensor brackets manually}
}
```

Comment: I contend that also `\left\{W_{ij\right\}` is wrong and it should simply be `\{W_{ij}\}`.

Comment: @egreg (Deleted my previous comment.) Actually, I suspect it was just there for comparison with `Bmatrix` for testing, but only the OP can confirm that.

Comment: Many thanks, the solution is such simple knowing the right command... (-:

Comment: @egreg: It´s the thing Nicola perceived, `\left\{W_{ij}\right\}` i added only to show what I expect from Bmatrix. Problem with your recommendation will be, no automatic adjustment of brackets height. Compare e.g: `\left\{\dfrac{1}{2}}\right\}` and `\{\dfrac{1}{2}\}`