# amsmath \Bmatrix & xcolor \rowcolors inside a table?

Tags: color, amsmath, longtable, tabu

I´d like to use an environment from amsmath-package together with rowcolors from xcolor-package for an entry inside a tabu-environment.

Problem is: using \rowcolors the left bracket from Bmatrix is not shown.

I think it´s a kind of expanding-problem like in my post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328414/how-to-use-amsmath-environment-bmatrix-inside-a-glossary).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
table      % Load the colortbl package
]{xcolor}
% table colors 
\colorlet{tablebodycolor}{white!100}
\colorlet{tablerowcolor}{gray!10}
%
\begin{document}
%    
\begin{table}
    \rowcolors{2}{tablebodycolor}{tablerowcolor}
    \begin{longtabu}{|cc|}
        \hline
        \bfseries column1   &   \bfseries column2                   \\
        \hline
        working             &   not working                         \\
        a                   &   $\begin{Bmatrix}M_{ij}\end{Bmatrix}$\\
        \dots               &   \dots                               \\
        \dots               &   \dots                               \\
        \dots               &   \dots                               \\
        \hline
    \end{longtabu}
\end{table}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: just for information: the problem extends to all `...matrix` environments defined by `amsmath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick hack to avoid the interference is to typeset the matrix outside in a box and to use the box instead of the matrix inside the table. Before the table:

```
\newsavebox\matrixbox
\setbox\matrixbox\hbox{$\begin{Bmatrix}M_{ij}\end{Bmatrix}$}
```

Inside the table:

```
    a                   &   \usebox\matrixbox \\
```

Another solution: Use plain TeX for the delimiters.

```
    a                   &   $\left\{M_{ij}\right\}$ \\
```

and use an array between them if you have several rows.

Comment: thanks, but that´s not a solution for my usage because I have many of those expressions

Comment: How many rows do your matrices have? One can do the matrices the old-fashioned way using `\left`, `\right` and an array (with suitable adjustment of spacing).

Comment: ... and there is no solution for amsmath ?

Comment: There is a solution for everything ;-) It's just a matter of effort (which is too big in my case).