# Customize TOC without titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, mwcls

I would like to futher customize my TOC, but it seems that I cannot include `\centering` or `\par` - e.g., for something like `\@chapapp\ \HeadingNumber\par`. Otherwise, color/size/font changes work fine.

```
\documentclass{mwbk}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter



\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries \LARGE % added for large font for chapters
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip %\@chapapp~ \par % added \@chapapp~ \par 
      #1\nobreak \raggedright % originally \hfil
%added for leaders (dots) in chapter in toc
%\xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
 %      \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
 %       mu$}\hfill%
%%%
\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss \itshape \fbox{#2}}\par\vspace{12pt} % ADDED VSPACE
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}  




%for mwbk
\def\mw@seccntformat#1{#1\enspace} % para tirar o ponto após número do capítulo

\renewcommand*\chapter@toc{%
  \ifHeadingNumbered\typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
        \ifHeadingNumbered
\mw@seccntformat{\color{ForestGreen}\@chapapp\ \HeadingNumber}%
        \fi
        \color{yellow}\HeadingTOCText}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  }




\makeatother





\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Some chapter}

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest using a \parbox, but for more than one line you might have trouble aligning the top to the left and the bottom to the right (although it can be done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what is desired, from the question, so I will make an assumption that it is the yellow text the OP wants centered in the TOC, but not in the document.  Also, how to handle multi-line entries of the chapter name in such a fashion?  For the general approach, I surrounded the heading TOC text with `\hfill`s, as in

```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
        \ifHeadingNumbered
\mw@seccntformat{\color{ForestGreen}\@chapapp\ \HeadingNumber}%
        \fi
        \color{yellow}\hfill\HeadingTOCText\hfill}%
```

However, that does not handle the multi-line chapter names.  For those, I require manual breaks using `\manbreak`, as in `\chapter{This is a really extra long \manbreak chapter name}`.  This macro is defined one way for the TOC construction, and `\relax`ed for the rest of the document by way of

```
\def\manbreak{\hfill\hfill\\\mbox{}\hfill\hfill}
\tableofcontents
\let\manbreak\relax
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{mwbk}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter



\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries \LARGE % added for large font for chapters
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip %\@chapapp~ \par % added \@chapapp~ \par 
      #1\nobreak \raggedright % originally \hfil
%added for leaders (dots) in chapter in toc
%\xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
 %      \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
 %       mu$}\hfill%
%%%
\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss \itshape \fbox{#2}}\par\vspace{12pt} % ADDED VSPACE
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}  




%for mwbk
\def\mw@seccntformat#1{#1\enspace} % para tirar o ponto após número do capítulo

\renewcommand*\chapter@toc{%
  \ifHeadingNumbered\typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
        \ifHeadingNumbered
\mw@seccntformat{\color{ForestGreen}\@chapapp\ \HeadingNumber}%
        \fi
        \color{yellow}\hfill\HeadingTOCText\hfill}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  }




\makeatother





\begin{document}

\def\manbreak{\hfill\hfill\\\mbox{}\hfill\hfill}
\tableofcontents
\let\manbreak\relax

\chapter{Some chapter}

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\chapter{This is a really extra long \manbreak chapter name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

While I don't know how to allow for `\par`s in the definition of `\l@chapter` or `\mw@seccntformat`, a similar approach with `\manbreak` can be used, here redefining `\def\mw@seccntformat#1{#1\Manbreak}`, where `\Manbreak` likewise has one definition in the TOC, and is `\relax`ed afterwards.

```
\documentclass{mwbk}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter



\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries \LARGE % added for large font for chapters
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip %\@chapapp~ \par % added \@chapapp~ \par 
      #1\nobreak \raggedright % originally \hfil
%added for leaders (dots) in chapter in toc
%\xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
 %      \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
 %       mu$}\hfill%
%%%
\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss \itshape \fbox{#2}}\par\vspace{12pt} % ADDED VSPACE
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}  


%for mwbk
\def\mw@seccntformat#1{#1\Manbreak} % para tirar o ponto após número do capítulo

\renewcommand*\chapter@toc{%
  \ifHeadingNumbered\typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
        \ifHeadingNumbered
\mw@seccntformat{\color{ForestGreen}\@chapapp\ \HeadingNumber}%
        \fi
        \color{yellow}\hfill\HeadingTOCText\hfill}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\Manbreak{\\\mbox{}}
\def\manbreak{\hfill\hfill\\\mbox{}\hfill}
\tableofcontents
\let\manbreak\relax
\let\Manbreak\relax

\chapter{Some chapter}

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\chapter{This is a really extra long \manbreak chapter name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Steven, that's great as far as it goes -- `\hfill` works, `\centering` doesn't, but actually I'd like to know how to have a paragraph brake in `\mw@seccntformat` or `l@chapter`, so that I can have "Chapter 4.\par etc...

Comment: @Joseph It is still not clear to me which element of the TOC you want to possess a paragraph break...the chapter title??

Comment: @Joseph Do I understand that you want the yellow text on a line below the green text, for example?

Comment: @Joseph Please see my edit.

Comment: Steven, yes, that's exactly what I was thinking about -- I'm still wondering why `\\\mbox{}` works, but a simple `\par` doesn't. I'm still working to center the green (chapter) also, but that's fine.

Comment: @Joseph See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-or-blank-lines.  `\par` requires `\long` definitions, which will break a lot of things at that level, if shoehorned in.

Comment: @Joseph As to `\\\mbox{}`, an `\hfill` needs something to push against, and that is what the `\mbox{}` provides

Comment: Indeed, when I changed to: `\mw@seccntformat{\hfill\color{ForestGreen}\@chapapp\ \HeadingNumber\hfill\mbox{}}%`, it got centered. I never imagined an `\mbox{}` would make such a difference. Many thanks.