# How to align figures vertically within a minipage?

Tags: minipage, vspace

I'm having trouble to define vertical spacing within a minipage, as \vspace seems to behave in a special way within it. For instance, in the example below I'd like to set the vertical spacing between figure A and B to 1cm, but it's being added at the end instead of in between the figures. What is the proper way of defining this spacing? Thanks, Jorge.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[!t]
\fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{minipage}}%
\hfill
\fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}}%
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

EDIT: Adding some blanks do alter the behavior, but I'm still unable to get it right; moreover; a spurious indentation appears!:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \\
        \\
        \vspace{1cm}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{minipage}}%
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it's nothing to do with minpage it would be the same without, you need a blank line before the vspace. Also `\noindent` in the `\fbox` is doing nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: thanks; adding some blanks does alter the behavior, but I'm still unable to get it right; moreover; a spurious indentation appears (I've noticed this before, why is that?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: (the \noindent in \fbox I also added because it too was adding unwanted indentation under some circumstances)

Comment: your edit is headed by a comment about blank lines but does not add any blank lines so with the `\\ ` the vspace will still be added after the second image. the indentation is because you have added a word space from the end of line after `\vspace`

Comment: the content of `\fbox` is set in horizontal mode so ther eare no paragraphs so no paragraph indentation so `\noindent` will do nothing. You probably had a space there note `\fbox{ a }` is not the same as `\fbox{a}`  `\fbox{\noindent a}` may appear to do something but it is just the lack of space token, `\noindent` does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `\vspace` mid-paragraph then the space is added, after the paragraph has been broken in to lines, after the line where the vspace appeared. That means

```
  a\vspace{1cm} b
```

will typeset a b and then add 1cm of space after that line. This behaviour is well defined but almost never what you want, it is almost always better to leave a blank line before the `\vspace` so that the previous paragraph ends and TeX is in vertical mode so the space can be added at that point.

```
a

\vspace{1cm}
b
```

typesets a above b with 1cm more space than usual.

Note this behaviour of `\vspace` is unrelated to it being in a `minipage` or that the items in the paragraph are subfigures.

Comment: :thanks! could you please tell me why did the \\ in my didn't work? I thought it was the same as a blank line. Also, why does it add (unwanted) indentation?

Comment: `\\ ` is not at all like a blank line and does not end the paragraph see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-or-blank-lines/82666#82666

Comment: Thanks so much for the link, now everything is much clearer!

Comment: I'm still wondering though about that spurious indentation which I run into time and again in many contexts... what causes it?

Comment: @dontpanic you added it, it is the space token (from end of line} that you added after `\vspace`  if you do not have a blank line above then the space is seen in horizontal mode, so makes a word-space

Comment: Thanks a million! That's something I've been wondering for a long time! Who would have imagined that a single `%` can make such a difference! (`\vspace{1cm}` vs. `\vspace{1cm}%`)!!!

Comment: @dontpanic well of course it's only needed because the blank line was missing as spaces are ignored in vertical mode. in horizontal mode, it is the difference between `dont panic` and `dontpanic`