# How to put caption in center in table and remove the "Table" from the caption?

Tags: beamer, captions

[image]

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcolumntype{2}{D{.}{}{2.0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{GF(2)}
 The simplest finite field is $GF(2)$. It's arithmetic operation are easily summarized:
 \\
\begin{columns}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\noindent
\begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
  \begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{2}}
+ & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Addition}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
  \begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{2}}
x & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Multiplication}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
  \begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{2}}
x & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Inverse}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
 \end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

I want to align the tables and their captions. I want to show caption as "addition", "multiplication", "Inverse" without the "Table".

Comment: Just do `\usepackage[labelformat=empty,justification=centering]{caption}` and perhaps add `\centering` before each `\begin{tabular}`. (Much simpler than playing with Galois fields... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real benefit from using a caption in beamer is that the word "Table" is added. So instead of trying to remove the word, why use a caption in the first place?

---

Some other comments:

- as said several times, you don't need `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer
- the correct syntax for passing options to the xcolor package is `xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}`.
- you should also not use `\\` to get a new line before the columns environment (see [When to use \par and when \\, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/36296)).
- Another thing which I don't understand: why are you specifying 4 columns if your tables only have 3?
- your definition of the "2" column type is for numbers with more digits. You probably noticed that the columns consequently get too wide (a problem you try to solve with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt})`. Instead you could define a suitable column type or simply use a standard `c` column as your numbers don't have any decimal marks to align.

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{GF(2)}

The simplest finite field is GF(2). It's arithmetic operation are easily summarized:
\bigskip
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{c}}
+ & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}
Addition
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{c}}
x & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}
Multiplication
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{c}}
x & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}
Inverse
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 4 instead of 3. yes, this is done by mistakenly.