# How to increase linestretch in inline-enumeration with enumitem?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, setspace

I would like to increase the linespread within a group. Namely, the linespread within an inline-enumeration. For this purpose, I have the following code.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\parindent 0cm 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemjoin = \hspace{0.7cm}, label=\alph*)}

\begin{document}
{
\setstretch{2}
\begin{choices}
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
\end{choices}
}\\

\begin{choices}
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

Which produces 
[image: Output1]

I would, however, like to have only the first list spaced with double spacing. Like so

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\parindent 0cm 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemjoin = \hspace{0.7cm}, label=\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\setstretch{2}
\begin{choices}
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
\end{choices}

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image: Output2]

So, if I have only one list present, it works. As soon as there is another list, or other text, it doesn't. Can somebody help me?

Wrapping it in a minipage environment does the trick. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `\\` in order to terminate paragraphs. Also, don't load `enumerate` along with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{innerchoices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[innerchoices]{
  itemjoin = \hspace{0.7cm},
  label=\alph*),
  before=\noindent,
  mode=unboxed,
}
\newenvironment{choices}[1][1]
  {\begin{spacing}{#1}\begin{innerchoices}}
  {\end{innerchoices}\end{spacing}}

\begin{document}

\begin{choices}[2]
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
\end{choices}

\begin{choices}
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why and why? :) so why should I not end paragraphs with // ? and why should I not load enumitem and enumerate together? they are compatible, no?

Comment: @JohannesBleher ``\\`` is not to be used for ending paragraphs. Ever. And no, `enumerate` and `enumitem` are not really compatible.

Comment: alright. looked it up https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-or-blank-lines

Answer (score 4):

The package setspace offers an environment. You get the manual probably by typing `texdoc setspace`on the command line.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\parindent 0cm 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemjoin = \hspace{0.7cm}, label=\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{2}
  \begin{choices}
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \end{choices}
\end{spacing}

\begin{choices}
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
  \item $XXXX$
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

We get:

[image]

Comment: your answer is great. i was torn... sorry. I roled a dice...

Comment: @JohannesBleher That's allright, egreg needs the rep much more than I do.