# Changing the size of things doesn't work via \scriptsize, \normalsize, \large, etc. in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

You are supposed to be able to change the size of things via the commands

```
\large
\huge
```

etc. However, they don't seem to work in math mode. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
${\footnotesize Text\text{Text}}$\\
${\scriptsize Text\text{Text}}$\\
${\normalsize Text\text{Text}}$\\
${\large Text\text{Text}}$\\
${\Large Text\text{Text}}$\\
${\LARGE Text\text{Text}}$\\
${\huge Text\text{Text}}$\\
${\Huge Text\text{Text}}$\\
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image: changing font size doesn't work in math mode]

While regular text is resized accordingly, things directly in math mode don't change.

Edit: I don't just want do change the size of a complete formula (which is solved by the answer from Rmano) but of singular symbols inside the formula (e.g. an integral sign inside an underset) which seems to only be possible with the `\scriptscriptstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` command. Since there are only these four, how can you change it to different sizes (especially larger ones)?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in mathmode. In this case you have `\dispalystyle`, `textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. You also can leave math mode,and , in a group, change the fontsize and reenter mathmode.

Comment: The commands `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, and `\Huge` are for text mode; they are NOT to be used in math mode. For math mode, use `\scriptscriptstyle` (akin to `\tiny`) and `\scriptstyle` (akin to `\scriptsize`).

Comment: you should get a clear warning in the log about misuse of the comands

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, the font-size command work **only** in text mode. On the other hand, math typeset in the scope of font changing command will (normally) follows suit.

[Do not use `\\` in normal text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82666/38080), and notice that `\par` should be in the scope of the font changing command to use the correct line skip.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
{\scriptsize $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
{\normalsize $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
{\large $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
{\Large $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
{\LARGE $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
{\huge $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
{\Huge $a=b;\text{Text}$\par}
\end{document}
```

[image: output for the snippet above]

Comment: I would emphasis that  font-size command work *only* in text mode ...

Comment: Why not use \\ in normal text? I get that it doesn't create a lineskip of the same size as set by the command but so what? In normal text the fontsize doesn't change that often anyway (if at all). Especially if you only want a line break and no new paragraph, there seems to be no reason to use \par over \\.

Comment: @LukasFun , look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines