# KOMA-Script - paragraph new line without space and parskip

Tags: koma-script, sections-paragraphs, parskip

I am currently writing my master thesis with KOMA-Class `srcreprt` and I am a little bit weird about blank lines in paragraphs, parskips and sectioning vertical space.

As I have learned usage of `\\` as shown in the following mwe is some kind of bad style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
beforeskip=1em,
afterskip=1sp
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Ein Kapitel}
    \blindtext

    \paragraph{Ein Absatz}
    \blindtext \\

    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: Bad style example]

As I have read, it is better to use `\usepackage{parskip}`, remove `\setlength{\parindent}{0em}` and use blank lines instead of `\\`. This gives a slightly different look, but is almost the same. But pdflatex now throws the following warning:

> Usage of package `parskip' together(scrreprt) with a KOMA-Script class
>   is not recommended.

I figured out, that KOMA-Script offers the parameter `parskip` which can be used instead of `\usepackage{parskip}`. But this creates big vertical spaces for the sections. Especially there seems to be no way to reduce the spacing between the `\paragraph` and the following text:

[image: KOMA-Script parskip]

So my question is:
What is the "best" solution to go for? I guess it is the KOMA-Script option `parskip`. But how can I reduce the vertical Spacings? Especially the `afterskip` of `\paragraph`?

I also came across the following: When using `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` one should `DVI=last`. I did not really understand this. Also in combination with the scrmanual it confused me more then anything else. Is this something I should take care of?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KOMA-script makes the spacing before, within and after the heading dependent on `\baselineskip` and `parskip`, which the packages `setspace` and `parskip` increase. A document with 1.5 linespacing, no paragraph indenting, but space between paragraphs, tries to copy Word-layout, and will never look nice, even though it will look better than a Word-document.

Correct syntax to set fontsize in KOMAscript is `fontsize=12pt`. Also, you may omit the `a4paper` option, since this is the default for all KOMA-Script classes.

The line

```
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
```

also increases the spacing before, within and after the headings. In addition, when you increase the `parskip` value to have blank line between paragrapgh, this will increase spacing in headers. Use the internal command `parskip=true` or `parskip=half` to have blank lines between paragraphs.

In KOMAscript, you may redeclare the sectioning commands individually to revert (decrease) the added space.

Chapter is pretty easy, as you see from my example. To remove additional space after `\section`, `\subsection` , `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` commands, use `\RedeclareSectioncommand` and set `runin` false and `afterskip` to a negative value.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, chapterprefix=true, parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0em} % Not needed when 

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
innerskip=0.05\baselineskip,
afterskip=1\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .12\baselineskip,
beforeskip=-2\baselineskip%
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
runin=false,              %% NB! Important
afterskip=-0.5\parskip
]{section,subsection}


\RedeclareSectionCommands[
beforeskip=1em,
runin=false,
afterskip=-\parskip
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Ein Kapitel}
    \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \blindtext

\section{Ein Section}
\blindtext

    \paragraph{Ein Absatz}
    \blindtext

    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your mwe uses the `\\ ` solution, which is considered to be kind of bad latex style https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines 

And in addition, I don't want to reduce the spacings in the first image. That look fine.  My question is, how to reduce the spacing, when using `\documentclass[parskip]{scrreprt}` since this makes big spacing. Another question: What does `afterskip=1.25\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .12\baselineskip` mean? Why can't i just say `1.23\baselineskip` (1,25+0,1-0,12=1,23)

Comment: @TheShadow I just copied you MWE. I will update the MWE. Regarding afterskip: This is the way you get some stretch before and after the heading. The first figure is the normal space, the next is how much additional space Latex may add if necessary, and the third how much space it may remove if necessary to get a OK page break.

Comment: thank you for your help. In your updated MWE the blank lines between the two paragraphs is removed when removing the two `\\ `, because `parskip` option is missing. Whith `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,chapterprefix=true,parskip]{scrreprt}` the vertical space between `\paragraph{Ein Absatz}` and `\blindtext` is again very big, which i want to have reduced to just a normal `\newline`. So the actual Question is: How to replace `\\ `, since it is considered to be bad style AND keeping the normal line break after `paragraph` in KOMA-Script? Package `parskip` does it, but throws a warning

Comment: Let me explain: I do want to have a linebreak after the paragraph title `\paragraph{title}`, but I don't want to have spacing between the title and the following text. Additionally I want to have a blank line between paragraphs, but not a indent in the firstline. So the given mwe gives me the output I actually want to achieve, but it uses `\\ ` for linebreaks, which should not be used regarding to a lot of form posts (here and elsewhere).

Comment: @TheShadow Have a look at the updated answer. The new code should work according to you description.

Comment: Thank you. The v-spacing for the chapter is actually not my problem. I am fine with that. But the redeclaration of the `\paragraph` command did the trick for me. 1.5 linespacing, not paragraph indenting and space between paragraphs are actually requirements from my adviser, so I have to do it this way. Thank you for putting so much time into my problem!