# Is there a way to check whether we're inside a table?

Tags: tables, tex-core

I have a syntax highlighting program that outputs LaTeX code.  The generated code can be used in regular text or in a `tabular` to do more advanced layouts.

The generated LaTeX output includes `\my@eol` at the end of each line, which is essentially defined as `\par`.  Of course, this works in regular text but not in tables, so I'd like to conditionally use `\cr` if I'm in a table.

**How do I check if I'm currently in an alignment (tabular, array, halign, etc.)?**

Originally I defined `my@eol` in terms of `\\`, which worked in tabular as well, but based on the comment of Barbara Beeton in *[When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines/82666)* I changed to using `\par`.  Now I need to find a way to switch between `\par` and `\cr` as needed.

Here's what I've tried: I looked at the implementation of `tabular`, and noticed that it redefined `\par` and `\\` (the latter to `\@arraycr`, which eventually expands to `\cr`), so one solution would be to check whether `\\` or `\par` has been redefined, but that sounds very brittle.  I read [the documentation of `tabular`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) as well.
Then I looked at various sources of documentation to see if TeX has any sort of conditional (like `\ifvmode`) for alignments, but I couldn't find one.
Finally I also looked at the implementation of `\halign` (it calls `init_align`) in the source code of TeX, but I didn't manage to spot anything directly relevant (it seems to just change to `vmode` and set up `align_state` when entering an `halign`, but I'm not sure how to access `align_state` from TeX).

Comment: Are you free to use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: `\\ ` can change meaning (and do different things) in the tabular depending on the columntype, and if you use e.g. \centering. If you want to be sure to end a tabular row you should better use `\tabularnewline`.

Comment: @Mico not really, but I'm curious to know what a LuaLaTeX solution might look like!

Answer (score 2):

To see what environment you are currently in you can look at the value of `\@currenvir`: inside a `tabular` or `array` environment etc it will be `tabular` or `array`, respectively. This will not work for `\halign`. Nested environments will not be detected either, but that's probably OK in your use-case.

To make these tests I think that the easiest approach is to use `\str_case:onF` from [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3). The code below defines a command `\IfInTableTF` that you use as:

```
\IfInTableTF{true code}{false code}
```

The name is perhaps not the best name since `array`, `tabular` and `tabularx` environments all test positive. All the command does is define a new boolean and then use `\str_case:onF` to turn it on if we are in one of our favourite environments and turn it off otherwise. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_clement_if_in_table_bool% a boolean for table manners
\newcommand\IfInTableTF[2]
{
  \str_case:onF { \@currenvir }% check current environment
  {
      {array}    { \bool_set_true:N \l_clement_if_in_table_bool  }
      {tabular}  { \bool_set_true:N \l_clement_if_in_table_bool  }
      {tabularx} { \bool_set_true:N \l_clement_if_in_table_bool  }
  }{               \bool_set_false:N \l_clement_if_in_table_bool }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_clement_if_in_table_bool {#1} {#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \IfInTableTF{in table}{Not in table}

  \begin{tabular}{c}
    one \\
    two \\
    \IfInTableTF{in table}{Not in table}
  \end{tabular}

  \[
    \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\
      2 \\
      \IfInTableTF{in array}{Not in array}
    \end{array}
  \]

  \IfInTableTF{in table}{Not in table}

\end{document}
```

and here is the expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The test `\ifvoid\@arstrutbox` seems to work well at detecting being inside a tabular or array no matter how deeply nested below that alignment.

```
\newcommand\IfInTableTF{\ifvoid\@arstrutbox
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo\else
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}
```

Other candidates could be `\ifx\\\@arraycr` but that can be fooled by `\raggedright`; and `\@ifundefined{@preamble}` but some packages leave an empty definition when not in use.

(The tabu package does global setting of `\@arstrutbox` but appears to explicitly set it void when not in use.)