# LaTeX: Why \\ causes no paragraph break for fully justified text, but does so for \raggedright, \raggedleft, and \centering?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

***Note: This question is not about getting a desired visual effect in pdf, it is concerned with LaTeX/TeX internal algorithm.***

In the following code, presence of `\\` sometimes produces a new internal tex-paragraph when encountered in the middle of a user-paragraph, and sometimes does not. In normal text mode, the only time it seems to not produce a new paragraph is when in fully-justified (default) alignment mode.

So the question is why did LaTeX team code this discrepancy? Was it to avoid changing the paragraph indentation for partial tex-paragraphs? Is it any better than starting a new paragraph with no indent in fully justified mode (like `\par\vspace{1cm}\noindent` instead of `\\[1cm]`)?

Code (lualatex):

```latex
% >> lualatex par_vs_backslashes.tex
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
    nodetree = require"nodetree"
    function filterprint(h)
        nodetree.print(h)
        return h
    end
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",filterprint,"filterprint")
}

\begin{document}

% This produces 2 tex-internal paragraphs
Hello\\[1cm] foo\par\vspace{1cm} world

\raggedright

% This produces 3 tex-internal paragraphs
Hello\\[1cm] foo\par\vspace{1cm} world

\end{document}
```

Console:

```
% Output for fully-justified mode:

├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent, width: 15pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: H, width: 7.5pt, height: 6.83pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: e, width: 4.44pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: l, width: 2.78pt, height: 6.94pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: l, width: 2.78pt, height: 6.94pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─ADJUST 
│ ╚═head:
│   └─GLUE width: 28.45pt
├─PENALTY penalty: 10000
├─GLUE stretch: +1fil
├─PENALTY penalty: -10000
├─GLUE subtype: spaceskip, width: 3.33pt, stretch: 1.66pt, shrink: 1.11pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: f, width: 3.06pt, height: 7.05pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─KERN kern: 0.28pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
│ ╚═  properties: {['injections'] = {['leftkern'] = 18350.08}}
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil

├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent, width: 15pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: w, width: 7.22pt, height: 4.31pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─KERN kern: -0.28pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
│ ╚═  properties: {['injections'] = {['leftkern'] = -18350.08}}
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: r, width: 3.92pt, height: 4.42pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: l, width: 2.78pt, height: 6.94pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: d, width: 5.56pt, height: 6.94pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil

% Output for rest of the modes (\raggedright, etc):

├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: H, width: 7.5pt, height: 6.83pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: e, width: 4.44pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: l, width: 2.78pt, height: 6.94pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: l, width: 2.78pt, height: 6.94pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil

├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: f, width: 3.06pt, height: 7.05pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─KERN kern: 0.28pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
│ ╚═  properties: {['injections'] = {['leftkern'] = 18350.08}}
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil

├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: w, width: 7.22pt, height: 4.31pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─KERN kern: -0.28pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: o, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
│ ╚═  properties: {['injections'] = {['leftkern'] = -18350.08}}
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: r, width: 3.92pt, height: 4.42pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: l, width: 2.78pt, height: 6.94pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: d, width: 5.56pt, height: 6.94pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: This question is to extend the understanding from 
a previous question-answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82666/192717

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This predates "LaTex Team" involvement, and goes back to Leslie Lamport's original LaTeX versions, so I can't really say "why" just confirm that your observation is correct.

The documented behaviour of `\\`  is that it never ends the paragraph, it just forces a line break, however in `\centering` and similar settings `\\`  is redefined and does, as you say, internally use `\par` which is a shame as sometimes that implementation detail becomes observable eg when `\parskip` is non zero (although latex tries to hide that by adding a negative \parskip space after the paragraph break introduced by `\\` )

```
\documentclass{article}

\parskip=1in
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  zzz\linebreak zzz aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  zzz\\ zzz aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  zzz\par zzz aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there another "cleaner" implementation possible for `\raggedright` `\raggedleft` `\centering` where they don't start new paragraph? Or is it something inherently impossible that caused the implementers to just start a new paragraph?

Comment: @reportaman the odd thing is not `\centering` starting a paragraph, but `\\ ` being `\par` in the scope of that command, it could (ignoring for simplicity the optional argument) be defined to be `\linebreak` for example, not `\par`.

Comment: Doesn't seem like `\linebreak` can do the same job as `\par`. Try adding `\vspace{\baselineskip}` after all the three: `\linebreak`, ```\\```, and `\par`. `\linebreak\vspace{\baselineskip}` doesn't add vspace right at the point it is inserted (between your zzz's), ```\\\vspace{\baselineskip}``` does! If there is no way to achieve that without starting a new tex paragraph, then it seems reasonable why it is coded as `\par` instead of `\linebreak`. What they could have done was to force `\parskip` to 0 for partial paragraphs, and making `\par` insertion consistent across all text justifications.

Comment: If you add `\vspace` after `\\ ` then the expected behaviour (as happens in normal justified text) is that the space comes _after_ the next line.

Comment: the way to add space at the linebreak is to use `\\[1in]` or put the vspace first `\vspace{1in}\\ ` @reportaman

Comment: Sure, thanks. Is that possible with `\linebreak` (as you suggest it to be a replacement to `\par`)? because `\linebreak\vspace{\baselineskip}` doesn't produce the desired effect & it doesn't accept `[\baselineskip]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116896/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-reportaman).