# What is the correct way to use `\\` or `\newline`?

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I want to end a line without ending the paragraph. Using`\\` or `\newline` gives me the the result I want, but also creates the 'Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)' warning. Using an empty line causes the next line to have an indent, which I don't want in this particular case. In other cases i might want to have an indent at the beginning of a paragraph, so I don't want to set the `\parindent` to zero.

Comment: you shouldn't get an underfull hbox warning if there is something on the second line. Better show a real,  small complete example.

Comment: The first question is: why would you want to “end a line without ending a paragraph”?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please always show a complete input. It is not impossible but highly unlikely to get badness 10000 from `\\ ` which is not at the end of a paragraph. You mean you have `line one\\ line two` and get that message?

Comment: What about occasionally using `\noindent` on selected paragraphs?

Comment: \centering (for example) defines \\ and \newline differently.

Comment: @user202729 if a non paragraph ending newline is intended then certainly `\\ ` is better markup than a blank line followed by `\noindent`, which is explicitly ending the paragraph

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The correct markup to  force a line break without ending a paragraph is `\\`  if you want the line to be short. This is very unlikely to give an badness warning on that line. (Paragraph 2)

If you want to force a line break but retain paragraph justification then use `\linebreak` (Paragraph 3) This may have to make an underful line and give a warning. Here it is very bad and maximum value 10000 but smaller values could be generated, or no warning at all.

A blank line always ends the paragraph (Paragraphs 4a and 4b)

A blank line followed by `\noindent` is usually wrong, it starts a new paragraph but obscures that from the reader (Paragraphs 5a and 5b)

If you end a paragraph with a blank line and force a linebreak at the same point with `\\`  you get a white spurious line generated. (It is a line of text with no text, not vertical space) and is always wrong and always generates a warning about the maximum level of badness (Paragraphs 6a and 6b)