# Huge amount of space between paragraphs in introduction

Tags: spacing

I'm writing my thesis in overleaf. I am using `\\` to indicate the end of a paragraph. This works perfectly for the entire document, besides for my first numbered chapter (all previous chapters have been defined as \chapter*{}).
My source text looks like this:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Glioblastoma}

blablabla.\\

blablablablabla.\\

blablablabla.\\
```

and shows up as the following:

[image: weirdly spaced text]

The problem stops once the next page starts. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Why are you using `\\\`? The empty lines you have imply new paragraphs.

Comment: `\\ ` does not end a paragraph _never_ use it at the end of a paragraph: it forces a spurious blank line and latex will warn you of badness 10000 (which is maximum badness)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines/82666#82666

Comment: If you prefer explicit ends of paragraph instead of blank lines , use `\par`, not \\. Anyway, set `\parskip` to some more than `0pt` (the default) if you want some space between paragraphs.