# How can I add text influenced by an option after the body of an environment?

Tags: environments, optional-arguments

I want to add text after the body of a `\newenvironment` after the main body of the environment. So the pseudocode would look like this:

```
\newenvironment{example}[2]{#1 \newline}{\newline #2}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}{This is before}{and this is after.}
    Hello World.
\end{document}
```

and format to:

```
This is before
Hello World
and this is after.
```

Comment: Remark on the usage of `\newline` →[paragraphs - When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You can achieve this with either [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ) or the LaTeX3 definition `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.