# Right Text Align

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

```
$ABC+A^{'}B+ABC^'$ \\
$= AB(C+C^{'})+A^{'}B$
\hspace*{1in} (Common Parantheses)\\
$= AB + A^{'}B$
\hspace*{1in} (Complement Law)\\
$= B(A+A^{'})$
\hspace*{1in} (Common Parantheses)\\
$= B$
\hspace*{1in} (Complement Law)
```

I want to align "Common Parantheses" and "Complement Law" according to the right of page. Actually, I want to do something like hspace but from right, or hspace but relative to page not to text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: [Don't use ``\\`` for new lines in normal text.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/16595) The `amsmath` package provides a lot of environments to align equations properly and which usually look good. Or are you not using LaTeX?

Comment: Off-topic: Both `^{'}` and `^'` are wrong. It should just be `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `^{'}` and `^'` are wrong and should simply be `'`.

I guess you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&ABC+A'B+ABC' \\
&\quad= AB(C+C')+A'B && \text{(Common Parentheses)} \\
&\quad= AB + A'B     && \text{(Complement Law)} \\
&\quad= B(A+A')      && \text{(Common Parentheses)} \\
&\quad= B            && \text{(Complement Law)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I see no reason for pushing the justifications to the right margin, nor the formulas to the left margin; actually, I see several reasons not to.

[image]

Is it possible to have the justifications at the right margin? Yes, certainly so. Compare

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text
\usepackage{showframe} % to see the margins

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{align*}
&ABC+A'B+ABC' \\
&\quad= AB(C+C')+A'B && \text{(Common Parentheses)} \\
&\quad= AB + A'B     && \text{(Complement Law)} \\
&\quad= B(A+A')      && \text{(Common Parentheses)} \\
&\quad= B            && \text{(Complement Law)}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{flalign*}
&ABC+A'B+ABC' \\
&\quad= AB(C+C')+A'B && \text{(Common Parentheses)} \\
&\quad= AB + A'B     && \text{(Complement Law)} \\
&\quad= B(A+A')      && \text{(Common Parentheses)} \\
&\quad= B            && \text{(Complement Law)}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you want your readers to have a hard time following lines with so large blank space between the two parts?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (The framelines at the edges of the text block are drawn by the `showframe` package.) The solution employs an `align*` environment and four `\tag` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'align*' env. and '\tag' macro
\usepackage{showframe}  % optional: draw frame around text block
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
ABC+A'B+ABC'
 &= AB(C+C')+A'B \tag{Common Parentheses} \\
 &= AB + A'B     \tag{Complement Law}     \\
 &= (A+A')B      \tag{Common Parentheses} \\
 &= B            \tag{Complement Law}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```