# Parskip is shifting my footer down

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, rules, parskip, scrlttr2

Why is the footer (containing the bank information) shifted down by parskip?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               DIN, A4,
               parskip=full, % removing this prevents the shift
              ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=20mm,
            inner=25mm,
            outer=20mm,
            bottom=30mm,
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}

% set the pagemark (page x of y)
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~von~\letterlastpage}%
    }

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\hfill\pagemark}

% create pagemark also on first page
\newcommand{\originalopening}{}
\let\originalopening\opening
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\originalopening{#1}\thispagestyle{plain}}

\KOMAoptions{fromalign=off,
             pagenumber=botright,
            }

\newkomavar[BIC]{BIC}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
    \hrule\vspace*{0.5em}\noindent%
    \usekomavar*{frombank}~\usekomavar{frombank} \hfill Sparkasse Deutschland \hfill
    \usekomavar*{BIC}~\usekomavar{BIC}}

% ===================================

\setkomavar{frombank}[IBAN]{DE98~1605~0000~7512~0130~19}
\setkomavar{BIC}{WELADED2PMB}

\setkomavar{toaddress}{Musterstraße 1}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Donald Duck \textit{\&} Daisy Duck}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Am Geldspeicher 1, 12345 Entenhausen}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
        \opening{Hello,}
        \Blindtext
        \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

When I uncomment `parskip=full` the footer gets shifted up although there is no `\par` in the footer..

Comment: there is  a \par at the \noindent, use e.g. `\hrule\vspace*{\dimexpr 0.5em-\parskip}\noindent` or reset `\parskip` locally.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Removing `\noindent` did not work. I had tried that before. How do I reset `\parskip` locally? Of course `-\parskip` does work but why is it even necessary?

Comment: there is a paragraph between the rule and when the text start, use \setlength to reset the parskip.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is there an implicit `\par` after `\hrule` as part of `\hrule` itself? Is there no easy ways to prevent it without removing it again afterwards with `-\parskip`?

Comment: AFAIK the low level TeX primitive `\hrule` does not switch to horizontal mode. So the `\noindent` results in switching to horizontal mode and therefore to start a new paragraph. IMHO: Using low level commands like `\hrule`, `\hbox` etc. is always dangerous, if you do not know, what you are doing. In LaTeX they should not be used as user commands. It is mostly recommended to use LaTeX user commands like `\rule`, `\hrulefill`, `\mbox` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use low level TeX primitive `\hrule` in LaTeX, at least, if you don't know the details of this primitive. Because it does not switch to horizontal mode, it does not start the paragraph. So the `\noindent` in your code starts a new paragraph an the setting of option `parskip` is used.

One possible change would be to use `\hrulefill` and just start a new line using `\\[<distance>]`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               DIN, A4,
               parskip=full, % removing this prevents the shift
              ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=20mm,
            inner=25mm,
            outer=20mm,
            bottom=30mm,
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}

% set the pagemark (page x of y)
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~von~\letterlastpage}%
    }

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\hfill\pagemark}

% create pagemark also on first page
\newcommand{\originalopening}{}
\let\originalopening\opening
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\originalopening{#1}\thispagestyle{plain}}

\KOMAoptions{fromalign=off,
             pagenumber=botright,
            }

\newkomavar[BIC]{BIC}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
  \hrulefill\\% You could also use something like \\[.5em] to move the following text down.
    \usekomavar*{frombank}~\usekomavar{frombank} \hfill Sparkasse Deutschland \hfill
    \usekomavar*{BIC}~\usekomavar{BIC}}

% ===================================

\setkomavar{frombank}[IBAN]{DE98~1605~0000~7512~0130~19}
\setkomavar{BIC}{WELADED2PMB}

\setkomavar{toaddress}{Musterstraße 1}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Donald Duck \textit{\&} Daisy Duck}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Am Geldspeicher 1, 12345 Entenhausen}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
        \opening{Hello,}
        \Blindtext
        \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Or you can locally change option `parskip`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               DIN, A4,
               parskip=full, % removing this prevents the shift
              ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=20mm,
            inner=25mm,
            outer=20mm,
            bottom=30mm,
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}

% set the pagemark (page x of y)
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~von~\letterlastpage}%
    }

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\hfill\pagemark}

% create pagemark also on first page
\newcommand{\originalopening}{}
\let\originalopening\opening
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\originalopening{#1}\thispagestyle{plain}}

\KOMAoptions{fromalign=off,
             pagenumber=botright,
            }

\newkomavar[BIC]{BIC}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=false}%
    \hrule\vspace{.5em}\noindent
    \usekomavar*{frombank}~\usekomavar{frombank} \hfill Sparkasse Deutschland \hfill
    \usekomavar*{BIC}~\usekomavar{BIC}}

% ===================================

\setkomavar{frombank}[IBAN]{DE98~1605~0000~7512~0130~19}
\setkomavar{BIC}{WELADED2PMB}

\setkomavar{toaddress}{Musterstraße 1}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Donald Duck \textit{\&} Daisy Duck}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Am Geldspeicher 1, 12345 Entenhausen}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
        \opening{Hello,}
        \Blindtext
        \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I did not know about not using `\hrule`. Strangely with `\hrulefill` you add a `\\` and still no `\parskip` is applied. Why is that?

Comment: @mrCarnivore `\\ ` or `\\[<distance>]` is not `\par`.

Comment: It is not? What is the difference? `\\` is a newline and `\par` ends the paragraph? I always thought they behave the same way...

Comment: @mrCarnivore Then, unfortunately, you have always been wrong. Also, please note that comments are not the right place to discuss differences between paragraphs and new lines. See also: [When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664)

Comment: Thanks for the link and the explanations!