# how can I write an inline hexadecimal value?

Tags: text, programming

How do I write an inline "\0x" without having LaTeX put each value on a new line?

"\0x" in C programing identifies a hexadecimal value. I would like to write an inline string of hexadecimal represented values.

Consider this as what I want to write

```
\0x68 \0x6F \0x77 \0x20 \0x64 \0x6F \0x3F
```

I tried

```
\\0x68 \\0x6F \\0x77 \\0x20 \\0x64 \\0x6F \\0x3F
```

but every hexadecimal value is placed on a newline, and missing the backslash.

I also tried

```
\texttt{\0x68\0x6F\0x77\0x20\0x64\0x6F\0x3F}
```

but the same thing happens.

Comment: `\verb|\0x68|` or `\textbackslash 0x68`  for example

Comment: very good! thank you, this works!

Comment: The double backslash in LaTeX represents an end-of-line.  It's generally not recommended except in particular well-defined environments.  Here's a previous question that addresses the situation: [When to use `\par` and when ``\\``](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\0[3]{\texttt{\string\0#1#2#3}}
\begin{document}

\0x68 \0x6F \0x77 \0x20 \0x64 \0x6F \0x3F

\end{document}
```

Comment: How does it work? The number in the command name

Comment: you can have one-character command names with non letters, so `\0` here, just like standard commands such as `\$` or `\^` which are non-letter commands. @Mane32

Answer (score 4):

If you have many of these, it makes sense to define your own command, say `\hexa`

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hexa}{sm}
 {% * means also compute the representation
  % #2 = number to represent
  \texttt
   {
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
     {
      \joh_hexa:e { \int_to_Hex:n { #2 } }
     }
     {
      \joh_hexa:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \joh_hexa:n
 {
  \char_generate:nn { `\\ } { 12 } 0x #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joh_hexa:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hexa{68} \hexa{6F} \hexa{77} \hexa{20} \hexa{64} \hexa{6F} \hexa{3F}

\hexa*{123456}

\hexa*{\value{page}}

\end{document}
```

You see that with `\hexa*` TeX will do the conversion to hexadecimal for you and you can even use a LaTeX counter as shown.

[image]

Using a command is better because, if you later change your mind and, for instance, decide to not use the backslash, you can just change the definition in a single place.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with several instances of `\string`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\string\0x68\string\0x6F\string\0x77\string\0x20\string\0x64\string\0x6F\string\0x3F}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The value \texttt{\textbackslash0x68} is a hexadecimal code.

\end{document}
```