\\ suddenly stopped working
I was working in a Latex doc in Kile, and suddenly \\ stopped working.
I am compiling just some notes from my math class, and I need to know if there is a shorthand of \newline that I can use instead of \\.
Also, why is there a limit of using \\ in Latex?
Here is the code and document:
I am not adding a reproducible example as the code works perfectly in other computers.


As you can see from all the warnings, you shouldn't abuse \ for line breaks.

You should never add a screenshot of code, because it cannot be used reproduce the problem using copy&paste. Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Add a blank line before "Matrice rispetto...". But anyway: never use \\  outside tabulars or aligns: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines . Also you should read https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes#Paragraphs_and_new_lines  (and probably all of that page )

@cabohah If I add a reproducible example, you will not understand the problem, because it stopped working in my pc, in other pc it works perfectly well.

To debug this we need a minimal example and the log-file. A screenshot is useless. But it is actually not worth the time: as already said in the other comments almost all your use of \\  are wrong. Remove all of them (with the exception of the one in pmatrix). If spacing is then not to your liking ask a new question with an example and someone will tell you how to get the right spaces.

@AnisaB. "in other pc it works perfectly well" --- the line starting with Matrice rispetto will be on the same line as the matrix before in every LaTeX implementation --- so that's not true. It is not excactly the same file.

@Rmano I’ll definitely claim my right to use \\ when typing addresses or after “Best regards”.

@Rmano Matrice rispetto etc that you see in Latex file is not the same as showed in output. Read the whole sentence at least  please

@Gaussier well yes, but that's a very specific usage ;-)

you have 561 bad boxes, so not surprising the output looks bad.

Apart from the fact that you should try to avoid using \\ for line breaks: If the code runs on one machine but not on the other, than you should look at what the log file(s) tells you. The first error is often the most meaningful one. Check that your TeX distribution is up to date. If you can't provide a MWE or at least the output of your log file, it will be close to impossible to help you with your issue.

@JasperHabicht thank you. actually I updated the TeX distribution and now it works fine. I am sorry that the question is closed by some know-it-all because otherwise I would vote your answer as the one who solved it. Thanks again!
