# Insert a new line without \newline command

Tags: line-breaking

I'm searching for inser a new line just push the "enter" button on the keyboard.

Is there a solution?

This is the "boring" way:

```
\section{mySection}
    My really really really long text.\newline
    A new text line.
```

This is instead a shorter and really less boring way:

```
\section{mySection}
    My really really really long text.

    A new text line.
```

And this last solution is that i adopted, but if in a really long text it will create a lots of white space on the latex editor, and this is not really nice for me.

Is there a way to create a new line just with the following code?

```
\section{mySection}
    My really really really long text.
    A new text line.
```

Comment: That's going against everything TeX stands for... You may not realise it, but the fact that an EOL character in the input file doesn't result in a new line in the output file is really handy, if only for code formatting. If you really want to type your text that way, why not use a word processor instead?

Comment: You can use `\par` to obtain a new paragraph. It is different from `\newline` or ``\\`` which produce a line break (by the way, there is a `\linebreak` command, to break the line and justify the line before).

Comment: There is always \begin{verbatim}

Comment: I would really like to know why you need this. If you're typing regular text, you probably shouldn't be deciding where newlines go. If it's code, use `verbatim`.

Comment: Probably see also [plain tex - Is there a counterpart/antidote for \obeylines? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57318/is-there-a-counterpart-antidote-for-obeylines)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Wihouth figuring that you are trying to do exactly is hard to say, but  except form small chunks of text is just a bad idea make that the end of line (EOL) equivalent to `\\` or `\newline`.

I now that in the it is boring at first, but my suggestion anyway is learn 
[What is the difference between \newline and \\?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and), 
`\linebreak` and `\par` (See also [Downsides of using \par instead of two new lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/downsides-of-using-par-instead-of-two-new-lines) ) and then just use blank lines to make new paragraphs (not to make new lines) and as less as possible the line breaking commands (in the end of rows of tables ... and no much more.) since probably there are better ways to obtain what you want without any `\\`. (I am thinking in lists, boxes with text, etc.)

Said that, in addition to `obeylines` environment, another options are **`parse lines`** and **`verbatim`** environments. What is better depend of what you want, because the tree environments have several significant differences, as you can compare in this example:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Some colors to distinguish environments in the compiled example
\usepackage{parselines} 

% huge indentation of paragraph only for demonstration purposes. 
\setlength{\parindent}{5em} 
% some paragraph skip to better distinguish  lines of different paragraphs  
\setlength{\parskip}{.8em} 


\begin{document}

This is the \texttt{document} environment.
The \LaTeX{} commands are recognized here without problems. 
EOL (Linefeed and carriage return) are just ignored. But long lines are well formatted. Test: This is a long sentence to test the text wrap in a pragraph. 
\\ This is a new line with \verb|\\|.
\newline This is another \verb|\newline| .
\par This is a new paragraph.



This is another paragraph. Blank lines (no matter how many) means a new paragraph, \textbf{not a new line}. Note  that a new paragraph can add indentation in the first line and vertical space, as in this example (or not, depending of \verb|\parindent| and \verb|\parskip| values. 

\color{blue!50!black}
\begin{obeylines}
This is the \texttt{obeylines} environment
Some  \LaTeX{} commands can be included  
This is a new line, but treated as a paragraph. 
This is another line (and another paragraph).


Blank lines are just ignored.

Long lines are well formatted (as paragraphs). Test: This is a long sentence to test the text wrap in a pragraph. This is a long sentence to test the text wrap in a pragraph. 

\end{obeylines}

\color{red!30!black}
\begin{parse lines}[\noindent]{#1\\}
This is the \texttt{parse lines} environment (need the \texttt{parselines} package)
Some \LaTeX{} commands can be included also (but not all).  
This is a line.   
This is another line.



And blank lines are just blank lines.

Long lines are well formatted (as lines): Test: This is a long sentence to test the text wrap in a pragraph. This is a long sentence to test the text wrap in a pragraph. 
\end{parse lines}

\color{green!30!black}
\begin{verbatim}
This is the verbatim environment.
The \LaTeX{} command are NOT recognized here. 
And use teletype text (as using \textt{})
But linefeed and carriage return are recognized.
So this is a new line


And blank lines are just blank lines.

And long lines are just long lines: Test: This is a long sentence to test the text wrap in a pragraph. This is a long sentence to test the text wrap in a pragraph. 

\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use `\obeylines`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bgroup\obeylines
Here line breaks
are respected.
\egroup
Here they
are not.
\end{document}
```

[image: breaks]

Comment: This is pretty fantastic!! For use it in my entire document i need to put `\bgroup\obeylines` after `\begin{document}` and it's done? right?

Comment: @RikyTres --- `\obeylines` stays in effect until the end of the current group, so you don't need the `\bgroup` and `\egroup` if you want it to affect the entire document.

Comment: Just a warning: when `\obeylines` is active,  table commands like `hline` will fail.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily try the following:

```
\\
```

It has the same result as

```
\newline
```

Comment: Ok, this is another solution, but it's not what I'm searching for...

Comment: I'm searching for a way to do a new line without any command... no `\\ ` , no `\newline` and no empty line. Is there a solution like this?

Answer (score 4):

I like environments, so I am going to embellish Ian Thomson's answer. I liked this idea so much, I wrote my own class in my user texmf directory that makes this code easily accessible to all of my documents:

```
% This code block makes it possible to process each line as #1 by defining \doline#1{#1}
\newenvironment{dolines}{\begingroup\obeylines\getlines}%
  {\endgroup}
\def\marker{\end{dolines}}
{\obeylines
\gdef\getlines#1
  {\def\text{#1}%
  \ifx\text\marker \let\next\text
    \else \doline{#1}\let\next\getlines \fi
  \next}}
\def\doline#1{#1\par}
```

You can redefine \doline however you want. For example, to center the text:

```
\def\doline#1{\parskip=2mm\centering#1\par}
```

I use it to typeset vocabulary lists or poetry.

```
\begin{dolines}
My really really really long text.
A new text line.
\end{dolines}
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way is to use

```
Sentence \\
~\\
Sentence
```

The key command here is `~\\`