# What is the difference between \\, \par, and blank line

Tags: line-breaking

Checking today [this topic](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=89649#p89615), they talk about the difference between `\\`, `\par`, and even a new line. And that people does not know the difference. And indeed, I don't know it.

Can you enlight me? And explain the main differences and good uses practices of each (if relevant?.

Related to this one is [What is the difference between \newline and \\?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and), but in there there is not an in depth differentiation (which I will like to know), and don't talk about `\par` or even blank lines.

Comment: A blank line is internally parsed as `\par`.  So a blank line and `\par` don't differ.  `\\` is generally used in `tabular` like environments for ending that line, but can be used to create a new line in other contexts too.  `\newline` and `\\` differ in  a regular context in that `\newline` manages the line spacing better

Comment: I think a more appropriate question to link to is [When to use \par and when \\\](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664) which yours appears to be a duplicate of.

Comment: You might also consider [this link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153595/22413)