# How do I automatically add linebreaks "\\" to the end of each row of a tabular environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, line-breaking

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Cycle Number and Phase}} \\
        \hline
        t & $ \phi $ & I  \\
        \hline
        6911.68158278 & 0.6843291408376899 & -1
        6911.69533917 & 0.6966511591836024 & -1
        6911.70882358 & 0.7087295567434921 & -1
        6911.7216598  & 0.7202273507382415 & -1
        6911.73451918 & 0.7317458898514815 & -1
        6911.74735541 & 0.7432436928038442 & -1
        6911.76036523 & 0.7548969856170515 & -1
        6911.77317833 & 0.7663740703219446 & -1
        9046.86818608 & 0.23613219262733764 & 1912
        9129.52570639 & 0.27499570945110463 & 1986
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

For a code like the one shown, I'm trying to make line breaks in each line in order to make it output as a table. There is currently no character after the "-1" or the "1912". But I wish there to be a '\\' after all of that. How do I go about doing so? I tried using the find and replace function that many tex editors have but without a character to replace, I can't seem to do so.

Also, just to clarify, this is actually a 100+ line table with ending values not always equal to -1, so I can't just replace all the -1 with '-1 \\'.

Comment: With regular expressions, if your editor manages them. Namely, replacing the (invisible) end-of-line  character with `end-of-line character \\ `.

Comment: Not an actual LaTeX-based solution, but anyway: many Editors (such as VS Code with the LaTeX-Workshop extension) give you the ability to place multiple cursors. By holding shift it creates mutliple cursors over a range of lines (at least VSC). While pressing Ctrl you can easily move with your arrow keys between beginnings/ends of numbers or words simultaneously. This helped me alot in situations like yours.

Comment: If you say which editor you use, we could help more (even if it's sort-of off topic). In `vim` visual block mode it's quite trivial...

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for this, just search for `\n` (the newline character) and replace with `\\\n`. In Windows you may need to replace `\r\n` (carriage [r]eturn line feed, CRLF). In some editors you need to switch on a 'control characters' option with search and replace to find such characters (also for example `\t` for a tab character), in other editors this is enabled by default.

Comment: I use texstudio for most of my latex work. It's pretty nice. But it doesn't have a \n character in the line. That was one of the first things I tried. So in my case, or at the very least, texstudio's case, there literally was no "end-of-line character". Or, the more likely explanation is that I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plain TeX approach: Use `\obeylines`

```
\begin{center}
  \bgroup
    \let\par=\cr
    \obeylines%
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }%
        \hline%
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Cycle Number and Phase}}
        \hline%
        t & $ \phi $ & I
        \hline%
        6911.68158278 & 0.6843291408376899 & -1
        6911.69533917 & 0.6966511591836024 & -1
        6911.70882358 & 0.7087295567434921 & -1
        6911.7216598  & 0.7202273507382415 & -1
        6911.73451918 & 0.7317458898514815 & -1
        6911.74735541 & 0.7432436928038442 & -1
        6911.76036523 & 0.7548969856170515 & -1
        6911.77317833 & 0.7663740703219446 & -1
        9046.86818608 & 0.23613219262733764 & 1912
        9129.52570639 & 0.27499570945110463 & 1986
        \hline%
    \end{tabular}%
  \egroup
\end{center}
```

I guess this will be frowned about by some LaTeX purists as we go under the hood of the macro package, but it's a very tiny intervention and does not require any external tools or additional packages.

A few words on what the above actually does:

- After `\obeylines`, and until the end of the current brace level, every line ending that is not masked by `%` is translated to `\par`. Which is normally the same as a blank line, and which we redirect to `\cr`, which in turn is the same as `\\` in a tabular environment.
- Append `%` to every line where we do not want to have the said effect.
- Unfortunately `\obeylines` cannot appear in the body of `{tabular}`, so we have to place it outside and add a few more `%`.

More details about `\obeylines` etc. can be found in `tex/plain/base/plain.tex:517ff`

```
\let\bgroup={ \let\egroup=}

% In \obeylines, we say `\let^^M=\par' instead of `\def^^M{\par}'
% since this allows, for example, `\let\par=\cr \obeylines \halign{...'
{\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with %
  \gdef\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let^^M\par}%
  \global\let^^M\par} % this is in case ^^M appears in a \write
```

(The LaTeX base `latex.ltx` contains the same definitions, but omits the comment.)

Comment: This is wonderful. It's quite simple and easy to understand as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which performs the adding of the linebreaks "on the fly", during compilation. It sets up a Lua function called `addlinebreak`, which simply adds `\\` to the end of each line of input, as well as two LaTeX macros, called `\addlinebreakOn` and `\addlinebreakOff`. The former macro adds the Lua function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, and the latter macro removes the Lua function from that callback.

Note where I placed the macros `\addlinebreakOn` and `\addlinebreakOff` inside the `tabular` (actually, `array`) environment: The former should be placed at the *end* of the last line that precedes the group of lines which lack `\\` directives, and the latter should be placed at the *end* of the final line that lacks a `\\` directive.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode*' environment
\begin{luacode*}
function addlinebreak ( s )
  return s.."\\\\"
end
\end{luacode*}

%% two LaTeX macros:
\newcommand\addlinebreakOn{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", addlinebreak, "addlinebreak" )}}
\newcommand\addlinebreakOff{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "addlinebreak" )}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{ |c|c|c| } 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$Cycle Number and Phase$} \\
    \hline
    t & $ \phi $ & I \\
    \hline \addlinebreakOn
    6911.68158278 & 0.6843291408376899 & -1
    6911.69533917 & 0.6966511591836024 & -1
    6911.70882358 & 0.7087295567434921 & -1
    6911.7216598  & 0.7202273507382415 & -1
    6911.73451918 & 0.7317458898514815 & -1
    6911.74735541 & 0.7432436928038442 & -1
    6911.76036523 & 0.7548969856170515 & -1
    6911.77317833 & 0.7663740703219446 & -1
    9046.86818608 & 0.23613219262733764 & 1912
    9129.52570639 & 0.27499570945110463 & 1986 \addlinebreakOff
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: i feel like introducing an entire code and creating a few extra commands seems like a bit of an overkill for just adding extra things at the end, but hey it works. Can't argue with results. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=&, row sep=newline,
      columns/T/.style={column type=|c,column name=t, string type},
      columns/PHI/.style={column type=|c,column name=$\phi$, string type},
      columns/I/.style={column type=|c|,column name=I, int detect, set thousands separator={}},
      every head row/.style={
        before row={
          \hline
          \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Cycle Number and Phase}}\\
          \hline},
        after row={\hline}},
      every last row/.style={
        after row=\hline}]{
    T & PHI & I
    6911.68158278 & 0.6843291408376899 & -1
    6911.69533917 & 0.6966511591836024 & -1
    6911.70882358 & 0.7087295567434921 & -1
    6911.7216598  & 0.7202273507382415 & -1
    6911.73451918 & 0.7317458898514815 & -1
    6911.74735541 & 0.7432436928038442 & -1
    6911.76036523 & 0.7548969856170515 & -1
    6911.77317833 & 0.7663740703219446 & -1
    9046.86818608 & 0.23613219262733764 & 1912
    9129.52570639 & 0.27499570945110463 & 1986
}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Minor quibble ... in the last column, you've got a hyphen where there should be a minus sign.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Alas, a side effect of `string type`.  Otherwise it converts everything to numbers, and I would have to play with the numerical display parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is an `emacs` answer if you're using that editor. Just run `M-x query-replace-regexp` and then replace `$` by `\\\\`, possibly selecting first and replacing all.

The idea is that, with regular expressions, the `$` character designates the end of line.

Comment: You may want to spell out more clearly what you mean by “possibly selecting first and replacing all”.