# How can I escape plain text?

Tags: conversion, convert, programming-tools, text-only

How, given string of plain text one may produce equivalent latex code? For example

```
red fox
sauté
zażółć gęślą jaźń
\newline is a new line in LaTeX
Samp_Dist_Corr
```

would produce something like

```
red fox\newline
saut\'e\newline
za\.z\'o\l\'c g\c{e}\'sl\c{a} ja\'z\'n\newline
\textbackslash{}newline is a new line in LaTeX\newline
\verb|Samp_Dist_Corr|
```

(example output above is poor - `ę` and `ą` are not converted properly, Samp_Dist_Corr is displayed in other style than rest of the text...)

(based on [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text) and [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex) [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex))

`\obeylines` seems to be enough to handle newlines ([Insert a new line without \newline command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153506/insert-a-new-line-without-newline-command)) (though replacing `\n` character and `\r\n` combination with `\newline` text is the simplest part).

`\verbatim` is not a solution for escaping as I want LaTeX to manage linebreaks (and according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153595/69392 with `\verbatim` text wrap is disabled).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696997/convert-plain-text-to-latex-code-programmatically discusses this problem and mentions additional pitfalls, but no solution is mentioned

Overall, I would strongly prefer to use any existing library/script rather than create a new one and discover special cases over and over again.

I want to note that I would be happy about any script/library, in any programming language.

---

To avoid XY problem: I have multiple txt files with cooking recipes that I want to convert into a good looking pdf file. I am able to automatically separate each text file into title/ingredient list/cooking instructions/time necessary for preparing etc. So I want to produces a TeX file that is a merge of all reciped with necessary TeX formatting. Later I will produce pdf file by compiling text using `pdflatex`.

Situation is a bit complicated as recipes are in Polish so żółćęśąźńŻÓŁĆĘŚĄŹŃ are expected, also é and other foreign letters may appear in specialized words (like sauté) or in mentions of original recipe title - so I would prefer general solution over stuffing babel directive with massive list of languages (though maybe that is a preferable solution over escaping?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idea using `fancyvrb` (with the `fvextra` extensions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe} %to show boundaries, remove this line for normal output


\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{mateusz}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mateusz}
red fox
sauté
zażółć gęślą jaźń
\newline is a new line in LaTeX
Samp_Dist_Corr
whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
\end{mateusz}

\end{document}
```

I used `showframe` just to show the boundaries of the text block.

[image]

Comment: Small note for people who use Ubuntu and simply installed `texlive-full` - hack to get fancyvrb is to view https://github.com/gpoore/fvextra/blob/master/fvextra/fvextra.sty in raw mode and download it to folder where .tex file is compiled.

Comment: And according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te placing it in `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` would be even better.

Comment: Footnote to above: place .sty file in `/tex/latex/` subdirectory of TEXMFHOME!

Comment: @egreg Like ur hat.

Comment: Unfortunately it fails for section titles. I created http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357425/how-can-i-escape-plain-text-in-section-titles to cover this.

Answer (score 1):

> `\verbatim` is not a solution for escaping as I want LaTeX to manage linebreaks

The package `spverbatim` also allow line breaks at spaces. It work with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` with the appropriate preamble. For example with `xelatex`:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Do not use with pdflatex
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % with pdflatex only
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % with pdflatex only
\begin{document}
\begin{spverbatim}
    Long text where it is allowed line breaks at the spaces. 
    red fox
    sauté
    zażółć gęślą jaźń 
    \newline is a new line in LaTeX
    Samp_Dist_Corr
    So żółćęśąźńŻÓŁĆĘŚĄŹŃ are expected. 
\end{spverbatim}
\end{document}
```

> so żółćęśąźńŻÓŁĆĘŚĄŹŃ are expected, also é and other foreign letters

With `utf8` option in  `inputenc` package and `T1` option in `fontenc` you will have all the characters that you have showed. If there are others, you may need additional solutions. For instance, often I should use  `€` and `µ` symbols, but the above is not enough with the default font. There are differents solutions for this cases, for example, the `textcomp` package, or a font package as `libertine`, but also others packages with support for euro or greek symbols.

If you have problems with other symbols, consider switch to `xelatex` or `lualatex` with the `fontspec` package. Even then, you may need change the font to have the more odd glyphs. In some cases, even using fonts that are not in CTAN. For example, many (all?) fonts in CTAN do not have a glyph for the unicode mouse emoji (), but you can install a special font in your OS like `OpenSansEmoji` and use it with `xelatex` using `\setsansfont{OpenSansEmoji}` in the preamble and  `\textsf{}` in the body of the document (afaik there are only the sans version, therefore  you cannot use  within `verbatim` environment except with  `\setmonofont{OpenSansEmoji}`)

Comment: Note that it is useless for pdflatex (`Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.`) - and I am using LaTeX because I want to generate pdf diocuments.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny That is what it says the first sentence of the last paragraph (although indirectly by omission).