# How can I escape plain text in section titles?

Tags: text-only

How one may with section titled "zażółć gęślą jaźń" or "\newline is a new line in LaTeX" may easily escape them? It is ceratin that nothing there should be treated as LaTeX formatting.

There is a nice solution for normal text, described in [How can I escape plain text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344799/how-can-i-escape-plain-text/344804#344804)

Unfortunately it fails for `\section{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{escape}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{\begin{escape}\newline\end{escape}}
\begin{escape}
red fox
sauté
zażółć gęślą jaźń
\newline is a new line in LaTeX
Samp_Dist_Corr
whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
\end{escape}

\end{document}
```

fails with

```
! Argument of \FV@BeginScanning has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \section{\begin{escape}\newline\end{escape}}
```

Using `\section{\escape{\newline}}` is not changing neither outcome nor error message.

To avoid XY problem: I am using `pdflatex` to generate pdf files from plaintext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define also an inline version of `escape` and use `cprotect`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{escape}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}
\CustomVerbatimCommand\escapeinline{Verb}{fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cprotect\section{\escapeinline|\newline|}

This is inline: \escapeinline|??{xx|

\begin{escape}
red fox
sauté
zażółć gęślą jaźń
\newline is a new line in LaTeX
Samp_Dist_Corr
whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
\end{escape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Generally seems to work, though with high section count glitch appears - section number and start of section name are at the same place (http://i.imgur.com/FwUa2Q0.png).

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny That's a completely different problem. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/toc-text-numbers-alignment, for example.

Answer (score 2):

`verbatim` like commands and environments usually do not work inside arguments of other commands. `ltxdoc.cls`, e.g., defines `\cmd` and `\cs` to solve this. They do not escape sequences of text but are used to print commands. A very simple suggestion would be to use TeX primitive `\string`, but you have to protect it inside `\section`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{escape}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}

% from ltxdoc.cls:
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\cmd#1{\cs{\expandafter\cmd@to@cs\string#1}}
\def\cmd@to@cs#1#2{\char\number`#2\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{\texttt{\protect\string\newline} \cmd\newline\space and \cs{newline}}
\begin{escape}
red fox
sauté
zażółć gęślą jaźń
\newline is a new line in LaTeX
Samp_Dist_Corr
whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever
\end{escape}

\end{document}
```

[image]