# Why is my boldface command ignored in my homemade environment?

Tags: environments

Consider the following source :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{categorycounter}
\setcounter{categorycounter}{0}
\newenvironment{categoryname}[1][]{\stepcounter{categorycounter}\S\thecategorycounter.{\bf{ #1}}}{}

\begin{categoryname}{First category}\end{categoryname}

First category consists of blah blah blah.\newline

\begin{categoryname}{Second category} \end{categoryname}

Second category consists of bluh bluh bluh.\newline

\end{document}
```

I get the following ouptut :

[image]

Now, I want the category name to be in bold face, as indicated by my `\bf` command above. Why is it ignored ? What can I do to fix this ?

Here is the output I want :

[image]

Comment: I didn't check if this is the problem, but as a blind shot, it's `\textbf{#1}` --- `\bf` is deprecated (since 30 years!) and does not have any argument, it's just a switch.

Comment: Also, never use `\newline` in text... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153506/insert-a-new-line-without-newline-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`
2. Your main problem is the `[]` in the command definition that makes it to expect an optional argument `#1` ... But you expect to use `#1` as a mandatory one.

See changed code that gives your requested output

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{categorycounter}
\setcounter{categorycounter}{0}
\newenvironment{categoryname}[1]{\stepcounter{categorycounter}\S\thecategorycounter.{~{\bfseries #1}}}{}

\begin{categoryname}{First category}\end{categoryname}

First category consists of blah blah blah.

\begin{categoryname}{Second category} \end{categoryname}

Second category consists of bluh bluh bluh.

\end{document}
```

Edit: removed the `\newline` that doesn't offer something as mentioned in the comments...

Also you may want something inside the environment and not outside of it... In other case just create a command and not an environment.