# Skip line without commands in Latex

Tags: line-breaking

I would like to know if it is possible to change a line with just a normal skip with "enter" in latex. For example I want the document to recognize a normal line skip with enter as a new line in the document.

```
\begin{document}
This is a line

This is also a line
\end{document}
```

instead of

```
\begin{document}
This is a line
\newline 
This is also a line
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would \\ or \\\\ do the trick?

Comment: @Mat Yes it would, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do skips without them. Using some sort of package in the beginning. Leaving a line empty in the code gives a line skip in the file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: In both PlainTeX and LaTeX, empty lines trigger paragraph breaks (and hence line breaks). Are you asking how to get a paragraph break *without* a non-zero paragraph indent at the start of the next line? Please advise.

Comment: I think this example can help: *https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153506/insert-a-new-line-without-newline-command*

Comment: the two forms are not equivalent. a blank line is a new paragraph this will _not_ leave extra vertical space by default, but may do, depending on your settings. `\newline` or `\\ ` force a linebreak within a paragraph and should only very rarely be used. So the question is, why do you need a new line? If it isto start a paragraph, a blank line is the correct input.

Comment: What you are asking is normal TeX behavior. Empty line is `\par` and `\par` finelaizes paragraph and next line is next paragraph, i.e. next line.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not very clear and you provided no example document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a line

This is also a line

\end{document}
```

Is the standard markup for two paragraphs and adds no extra vertical space:

[image]

Perhaps you are using a class that instead of indentation uses vertical space to separate paragraphs, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

This is a line

This is also a line

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

In either case, this is a two-paragraph document and quite different from

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a line\newline
This is also a line

\end{document}
```

which is a one-paragraph document with a forced linebreak.

[image]

as is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

This is a line\newline
This is also a line

\end{document}
```

[image]