Adding line in multicols
I would really appresiate it if someone could help me out,
I am using the multicols package and have some code something like this
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}    
    \begin{multicols}{2}

        1) awe f awef vawse f WESF CWE f wAE FW Ef w F WEF Wfweasfvc sdfg rfsyt fh srt  sef awefaw f we afg awe g aer gf vaerfg aez grv aer fg aeSF AE DSF VAWES F we f we fv wes F wf WEF  wf we F  Wef  we F wef f
        
        2)  CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
        
        3) CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
        
        4) CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}

which gives an output as shown below, but I would really like to have blank lines show in the output so that there is more space between say 3) and 4). Any help is appreciated, thank you

A blank line is a paragraph break except in special environments. You can make TeX take them literally, but that is almost certainly not what you want to do here. Do you want extra space between each pair of items in the list? Or do you want to specify when you want the extra space on a case-by-case basis? And why are you numbering your list by hand?

@cfr - I’ve upvoted your comment for “And why are you numbering your list by hand?”

@Mico . . . . ;)

Thank you very much for the explanation, also, the numbers where just put in by hand for the question I was using \item in the actual problem, should have maybe included that. Thank you guys! I just wanted to specify when I wanted extra space just as shown by you below, thank you.

OTOH, I've always regarded enumerate as a crutch for people who can't count (or are constatnly reordering their points).

@JohnKormylo Just like hyphenation patterns - only people who can't decide where to break their lines or keep editing their text need the things, after all. Not to mention fonts - for people who can't draw.

@cfr - Ah yes, I miss caligraphy!

@JohnKormylo Never say it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153506/insert-a-new-line-without-newline-command.

Your formatting objective could be achieved by employing an enumerate environment.

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}

\begin{document}  
  
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt]

\item  awe f awef vawse f WESF CWE f wAE FW Ef w F WEF Wfweasfvc sdfg rfsyt fh srt  sef awefaw f we afg awe g aer gf vaerfg aez grv aer fg aeSF AE DSF VAWES F we f we fv wes F wf WEF  wf we F  Wef  we F wef f
        
\item CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
        
\item CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
        
\item CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg
     
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}


I upvoted your answer just for the image.

Thank you so much for the answer numbering list by hand just as an example, was using \item in an enumerate environment, but for some reason wasn't working, but I added the [left=0pt] bit that you have and deleted some of the stuff I had put in and everything worked as you said it should thank you

While it is possible to make TeX output blank lines as such, this is so only in particular contexts e.g. when typesetting code. Since all line-breaking is then manual, it isn't what you want here.
In general typesetting, a blank line is a paragraph break.
In addition, you shouldn't number your items manually.
Instead, use an enumerate environment which will both number items automatically and insert space between them. To reproduce your layout, you can use the wide setting from the enumitem package.
For example,
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}    
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*),wide]
    \item awe f awef vawse f WESF CWE f wAE FW Ef w F WEF Wfweasfvc sdfg rfsyt fh srt  sef awefaw f we afg awe g aer gf vaerfg aez grv aer fg aeSF AE DSF VAWES F we f we fv wes F wf WEF  wf we F  Wef  we F wef f
  
    \item  CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
  
    \item CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
  
    \item CAS F DSGV AED RG AER G ERAg ar eg aer g aerg  erg aer rg aerg vaerg vard gv aerg vaer g ae g aerg aer g aer gaer g WA G re g ERA G arewg ARE G erg 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

Note that the result is unlikely to look great if the input is random character strings, because TeX cannot apply any hyphenation rules (or, rather, it applies the default, unextended set for US English and finds no matches).

Using automated numbering means you can insert or delete items without renumbering everything. You can also label and refer to them.
\item \label{enum:my-item}My item

creates a label with the tag enum:my-item which you can reference elsewhere in the document.
See \ref{enum:my-item} on page \pageref{enum:my-item}.

You need two compilation runs to resolve the references.

Forgot to crop the stupid image ....

Thank you so much, very helpful

I've taken the liberty of uploading a higher-resolution image (and of upvoting your answer...) :-)

@Mico Thanks you!
